# ResultSet.getTimestamp("date") vs ResultSet.getTimestamp("date", Calendar.getInstance(tz))

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, sybase

`java.util.Date`, `java.util.Timetamp` were seems to be causing great confusion for many. Within StackOverflow there are so many questions, Unfortunately my question is bit twisted.

There are 2 JDBC api. How they should perform? Was there any consistencies among RDBMS’es?

```
ResultSet.getTimestamp("dateColumn") 
ResultSet.getTimestamp("dateColumn", Calendar.getInstance(tz))
```

If someone has knowledge in Sybase, could you please share your experience?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First, you're confusing `java.util` with `java.sql`. When using [`PreparedStatement#setDate()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate%28int,%20java.sql.Date%29) and [`ResultSet#getDate()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDate%28java.lang.String%29), you need [`java.sql.Date`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html). Analogous, when using [`PreparedStatement#setTimestamp()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate%28int,%20java.sql.Date%29) and [`ResultSet#getTimestamp()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp%28java.lang.String%29) you need [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html).

Second, it's important to understand that `java.sql.Date` represents solely the **date** (year, month, day) and nothing less or more. This is to be mapped to a SQL `DATE` field type. The `java.sql.Timestamp` represents the **timestamp** (year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond), exactly as the [`java.util.Date`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and [`java.util.Calendar`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) does. This is to be mapped to a SQL `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` field type.

As to the timezones, you need it when the database does not store timezone information (thus, all timestamps are stored in UTC (GMT)). You can then pass a `Calendar` in which contains information about the current timezone, so that the JDBC driver can adjust the UTC timestamp to the timestamp conforming the timezone. If it is for example GMT+1, then the JDBC driver will add one hour to the timestamp before returning.

Comment: Good answer. For more info on on the variations of the various Date classes in JDBC you may refer to my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305973/java-util-date-vs-java-sql-date/2306051#2306051