# How to set the date pattern on jsf pages?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

```
<rich:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
          <h:outputText value="Expiry Date"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{item.endDate}">

    </h:outputText>
</rich:column>
```

Using above code, I got the date from database is 2012-09-03 00:00:00.0

Now, I want to set the date pattern to dd-MM-yyyy.

So my required output is 03-09-2012.

But using below code (after setting the pattern)

```
<rich:column>
     <f:facet name="header">
         <h:outputText value="Expiry Date"/>
     </f:facet>
     <h:outputText value="#{item.endDate}">
          <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy"  />
     </h:outputText>
</rich:column>
```

I am getting the output is 02-09-2012

Whatever date is in database, it shows output less by one day.

In advance thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSF convertDateTime renders the previous day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351244/jsf-convertdatetime-renders-the-previous-day)

Comment: Thank for pointing me. Next time, I'll be careful for this.

Answer (score 1):

You should add suitable `timeZone` attribute to `convertDateTime` component.
For an example in my zone

```
<f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" timeZone="Asia/Calcutta" />
```

Note:

you can use `java.util.TimeZone.getDefault().getID()` to get your current time zone id.