# Schedule event is created in previous day

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to implement Primefaces Schedule with database:

```
        <p:outputLabel for="from" value="From:" />
        <p:calendar id="from" value="#{schedule.event.startDate}" timeZone="GMT+2" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"/>

        <p:outputLabel for="to" value="To:" />
        <p:calendar id="to" value="#{schedule.event.endDate}" timeZone="GMT+2" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"/>

        <p:outputLabel for="allDay" value="All Day:" />
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="allDay" value="#{schedule.event.allDay}" />

        <p:commandButton type="reset" value="Reset" />
        <p:commandButton id="addButton" value="Save" actionListener="#{schedule.addEvent}" oncomplete="PF('myschedule').update();PF('eventDialog').hide();" />

        <p:commandButton value="Delete" oncomplete="PF('myschedule').update(); PF('eventDialog').hide();"
                         actionListener="#{schedule.deleteEvent}"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:dialog>
```

**CDI Bean:**

```
@Resource(name = "jdbc/DefaultDB")
private DataSource ds;
private ScheduleModel lazyEventModel;
private ScheduleEvent event = new DefaultScheduleEvent();

@PostConstruct
public void init()
{
    lazyEventModel = new LazyScheduleModel()
    {
        @Override
        public void loadEvents(Date start, Date end)
        {
            try
            {                   
                Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement ps = null;
                try
                {
                    ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM SCHEDULE WHERE START_DATE >= ? AND END_DATE < ?");

                    ps.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(start.getTime()));
                    ps.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(end.getTime()));
                    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                    while (rs.next())
                    {
                        addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent(rs.getString("TITLE"), rs.getDate("START_DATE"), rs.getDate("END_DATE")));
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (ps != null)
                    {
                        ps.close();
                    }
                    conn.close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
}

public ScheduleModel getEventModel()
{
    return lazyEventModel;
}

public ScheduleEvent getEvent()
{
    return event;
}

public void setEvent(ScheduleEvent event)
{
    this.event = event;
}

public void addEvent(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws Exception
{
    String title = event.getTitle();
    String description = event.getDescription();
    Date startDate = event.getStartDate();
    Date endDate = event.getEndDate();

    if (event.getId() == null)
    {
        insertData(title, description, startDate, endDate);
        lazyEventModel.addEvent(event);
    }
    else
    {
        updateData(title, description, startDate, endDate);
        lazyEventModel.updateEvent(event);
    }
    event = new DefaultScheduleEvent();
}

public void deleteEvent(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws Exception
{
    String title = event.getTitle();
    delete(title);
    lazyEventModel.deleteEvent(event);
}

public void onEventSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent)
{
    event = (ScheduleEvent) selectEvent.getObject();
}

public void onDateSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent)
{
    event = new DefaultScheduleEvent("", (Date) selectEvent.getObject(), (Date) selectEvent.getObject());
}

public void onEventMove(ScheduleEntryMoveEvent event) throws Exception
{
    String title = event.getScheduleEvent().getTitle();
    String description = event.getScheduleEvent().getDescription();
    Date startDate = event.getScheduleEvent().getStartDate();
    Date endDate = event.getScheduleEvent().getEndDate();

    updateData(title, description, startDate, endDate);

    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Event moved", "Day delta:" + event.getDayDelta() + ", Minute delta:" + event.getMinuteDelta());

    addMessage(message);
}

public void onEventResize(ScheduleEntryResizeEvent event)
{
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Event resized", "Day delta:" + event.getDayDelta() + ", Minute delta:" + event.getMinuteDelta());

    addMessage(message);
}

private void addMessage(FacesMessage message)
{
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
}

public void updateData(String title, String description, Date startDate, Date endDate) throws SQLException, Exception
{
    Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    boolean committed = false;
    try
    {
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        String updateComponentStats = "UPDATE SCHEDULE SET TITLE = ?, START_DATE = ?, END_DATE = ?, DESCRIPTION = ?, LAST_UPDATED = CURRENT_DATE WHERE TITLE = ?";

        ps = conn.prepareStatement(updateComponentStats);
        ps.setString(1, title);
        ps.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(startDate.getTime()));
        ps.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(endDate.getTime()));
        ps.setString(4, description);
        ps.setString(5, title);

        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();

        conn.commit();
        committed = true;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (!committed)
        {
            conn.rollback();
        }

        if (ps != null)
        {
            ps.close();
        }
        conn.close();
    }
}

public void insertData(String title, String description, Date startDate, Date endDate) throws SQLException, Exception
{
    Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    boolean committed = false;
    try
    {
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        String updateComponentStats = "INSERT INTO SCHEDULE (TITLE, START_DATE, END_DATE, DESCRIPTION, CREATED) "
            + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, CURRENT_DATE)";
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(updateComponentStats);

        ps.setString(1, title);
        ps.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(startDate.getTime()));
        ps.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(endDate.getTime()));
        ps.setString(4, description);

        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();

        conn.commit();
        committed = true;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (!committed)
        {
            conn.rollback();
        }

        if (ps != null)
        {
            ps.close();
        }
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

When I create new event using dialog I successfully create new event into previous day. I convert `java.util.Date` to `java.sql.Date` when I insert new event.

Can you give some idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Could you try to remove timeZone-attribute just to see if its related to that

Comment: I removed it but there is no change. I get the same wrong day.

Comment: Please be more specific... Is the schedule already sending the wrong date/time? Then it is NOT database related. If it is sending the right date/time and the storing fails, it is NOT jsf/PrimeFaces related.

Comment: I click on 21.06 to create event. When It's ready it's created on 20.05.

Comment: READ what I ask... This is not being specific... It is just as vague (and it is even a day and a month difference... Typo?

Comment: You're missing the code that is calling the loadEvents and the jsf code that displays it.

Comment: I updated my post - this is the complete code. Can you post an answer which code I'm missing?

Comment: Try to print/debug the date objects that are created inside your `addEvent` method. What do you get for `startDate` and `endDate`?

Comment: Your problem could be related with timezone configuration in JSF. Check that your server timezone has the right value. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351244/jsf-convertdatetime-renders-the-previous-day

Comment: can you put your schedule code please!

Comment: try to pass the java date instead of sql date into `addEvent()` method

Comment: Can you post code example please?

Comment: what is your database host timezone?

Comment: I have generic PostgreSQL installation. I haven't configure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .xhtml file, add this to it

```
<p:schedule clientTimeZone="local"> </p:schedule>
```