# Getting the date goes back one day

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, date, spring-mvc

I have an entity with the field

```
public class MovieReleaseDateEntity {
     @Basic
     @Column(name = "release_date")
     @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
     private Date date;
}
```

I save the date in the database

```
https://zapodaj.net/14dfcfb70926a.png.html
```

I get it after downloading it from the database

```
"date": "2017-12-06T23:00:00.000+0000"
```

The date is withdrawn by one day. Why?

Comment: In which timezone you are getting the date before storing it in dB.

Comment: I am in Poland.

Comment: What time zone is defined in your computer?

Comment: Is it exactly one day difference of few hrs difference? If it few hrs difference then it might be timezone issue.

Comment: Also refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300047/jpa-temporaltype-date-giving-wrong-date

Comment: this is a timezone problem

Comment: What value did you expect?

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

These all represent the very same point on the timeline, the very same simultaneous moment:

- 2017-12-06T23:00:00.000+0000
- 2017-12-07T00:00:00.000+01:00
- 2017-12-07T04:30:00.000+05:30

## Details

The [`Europe/Warsaw` time zone](https://time.is/Warsaw) is currently one hour ahead of [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

> "2017-12-06T23:00:00.000+0000"

Your string represents a moment in UTC. Note the `+0000`, an abbreviation of `+00:00`, which means an offset of zero hours and zero minutes from UTC. So it *is* at UTC.

That same  moment as seen thorough the lens of a clock on the wall on Poland is 00:00 on the morning of the next date. That is the first moment of the new day in Poland.

> "2017-12-07T00:00:00.000+01:00"

That same moment is later on a wall-clock in India where the people live five and a half hours ahead of UTC.

> "2017-12-07T04:30:00.000+05:30"

If an insomniac in Poland called their friend on the west coast of North America, they might catch their friend still on the job in mid-afternoon at 3 PM on the earlier date. There the clock on the wall is eight hours behind UTC.

> "2017-12-06T15:00:00.000-08:00"

Parse your input string as an `OffsetDateTime` object. To view the same moment in other time zones, adding a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Search Stack Overflow for details as this has been covered many many times already.

Avoid the troublesome flawed old date-time classes such as `Date`. Use only their replacements, the modern industry-leading java.time classes.

Answer (score 1):

It does not revert the day back, it retrieves the date in a different timezone, one hour less and it shows as a day before (so `2017-12-07 00:00:00` becomes `2017-12-06 23:00:00`). `java.date` and `java.sql` packages that you are probably using are just wrappers around milliseconds represented as *Longs* so timezone is also needed.

Check your time zone and check the timezone of your server and make sure they match. If you cannot change it for any reason, you can use date formatters to parse the time in a specific timezone when retrieving from the database

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by change the  mysql database column type from date to datetime