# Spring/Hibernate Date is one day earlier

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, date

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="friend")
public class Friend {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="birthday")
    private Date birthday;

    public Date getBirthday() {
        System.out.println("getter" + this.birthday);
        return this.birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(Date birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }
```

I am using `java.sql.Date` here to insert a birthday into my MySQL db. For the setter, I get the Date as a String in the form `yyyy-MM-dd` from a jsp page using form tags and model attributes. After setting, I checked my db table and the date is as expected, but when I call the getter, the date is one day earlier (e.g. If i have 2000-06-20 in my db, the getter returns 2000-06-19).

Comment: There's a reasonable chance that time zones are the issue and that what's logged in the `System.out.println` is different to local date time as rendered in the client.  There's 3 possible timezones in play: the MySQL Server. the server running the Java and the client rendering the date.  Usually servers (database and application server) are in UTC. You could have a decent read of the Joda Time library.

Comment: @GregHNZ is right but you don't have to use JodaTime anymore as since Java 8 there is the Java DateTime API and you can use LocalDate instead of java.sql.Date. But this my not solve your problem.

Comment: This issue is very likely a duplicate of ["date goes back one day"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47698294/getting-the-date-goes-back-one-day)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the date goes back one day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47698294/getting-the-date-goes-back-one-day)

Answer (score 3):

## Wrong data type

Never use `java.util.Date` nor `java.sql.Date` classes. These classes were terribly designed, and were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

And by the way, never write code that depends implicitly on some default time zone. That puts control of your results outside your hands as a programmer.

## `LocalDate`

To represent a date only, without a time-of-day, and without the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC, use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html).

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( "2000-06-20" ) ;  // Parses standard ISO 8601 format by default.
```

### Exchanging `LocalDate` objects with your database

Store a date-only value in a database column of a type akin to the SQL standard type `DATE`. Note that various databases vary *widely* in their date-time handling and naming, so study your documentation closely. In MySQL 8 specifically, use [its `DATE` type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html).

Write to database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , localDate );
```

Retrieve from database.

```
LocalDate localDate = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

If you following this approach, default time zones will be irrelevant. Your results will be consistent.

### Hibernate & JPA support *java.time*

As for your use of Hibernate, both [Hibernate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_(framework)) and [JPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API) were both updated years ago to support *java.time*. Be sure your [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) complies with JDBC 4.2 or later.

Searches: [Hibernate & java.time](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=hibernate%20java.time&t=osx&ia=web), and [JPA & java.time](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=JPA%20java.time&t=osx&ia=web)

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 1):

I had `serverTimezone=UTC` at the end of my jdbc url, and removing it seems to have fixed the problem. My database server and my Tomcat server seem to be using my local timezone.