# JPA+Hibernate date displays wrong data

Tags: java, spring, date, jpa, timezone

I user hibernate+spring+mysql 5.7. When I save date 20/04/1939, it stores correctly in database.

```
@Column(name = "birth_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date birthDate;
```

the value stored in database after save is 1939-04-20.

when i display it using

```
person.getBirthDate()
```

it displays 19/04/1939. It is not related with my formatting.
The value it retrieves from db is one day less.

It is always showing 1 day less when i use year 1939 with any date. So what's wrong here? 
Also for other years, dates are showing perfectly.

Comment: Looks like a time zone issue. What database are you using? What time zone is your computer using?

Comment: i m using mySql 5.5 as database and my timeZone is Bangladesh Dhaka

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA TemporalType.Date giving wrong date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5300047/5221149)

Comment: Sorry your link does not help me anyway.Please see the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

updating the database timezone solved this issue.

Comment: can you describe what exactly you did to solve the problem please, I have the same problem.