# sql.date vs util.date

Tags: java

As we have two date classes: `java.sql.Date` and `java.util.Date`. Whats the reason [`ResultSet#getDate()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDate%28int%29) returns the `sql.Date` not `util.Date`? 
Agreed that `sql.Date` extends `util.Date`. But whats the reason of creating new class altogether when most of the methods in both the classes looks same?

Comment: The documentation is pretty clear[ http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html ], and if you have a class for two different purposes, it's better that you'd have two classes.

Comment: See [java.util.Date vs java.sql.Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305973/java-util-date-vs-java-sql-date)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is right in the [JavaDocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) of `java.sql.Date`:

> *To conform with the definition of SQL DATE, the millisecond values wrapped by a java.sql.Date instance must be 'normalized' by setting the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero in the particular time zone with which the instance is associated*

So a `java.util.Date` has a "time" part, whereas in a `java.sql.Date` the time is always "zero" because the (ANSI) SQL `DATE` data type does not have a time either.

Comment: Same here! :)  You'll also notice that the toString() and valueOf() methods are overridden to parse/set the ANSI date format.

Comment: I am extremely sorry . I did not get the meaning of this statement written in javadocs.I read it before posting the query.Coulkd you please elaborate it little more?

Comment: I can only repeat myself: a DATE does not have a time, and that's what `java.sql.Date` ensures.

Comment: So is there any way we can store time part also in data store.As java doc said sql date has no time part