# java sql date time

Tags: java, date, jdbc

When I insert a SQL `DateTime` to the database I get `2007-02-07 12:00:00.00`

But I made the `Date` object like this : `2007-02-07 17:29:46.00`

How to get the value of the seconds in the database. It always changes it back to `12:00:00.00`

```
date.setYear(Integer.valueOf(parsedDate[2].replaceAll(" ", "")) - 1900);
date.setMonth(Integer.valueOf(parsedDate[0].replaceAll(" ", "")));
date.setDate(Integer.valueOf(parsedDate[1].replaceAll(" ", "")));
...
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
```

Should I use any formatters?

Comment: A "Date" (a number representing some point in time) is INDEPENDENT of it's format (the *same* number can be represented as "2007-02-07" or "2007-07-02" or "2/7/2007".  It's also independent of your time zone (the same number can be "2/7/2007" in Los Angeles, and "2/8/2007" in London).  Finally a "date" (e.g. "2/7/2007") has a different value than a datetime (e.g. "2/7/2007 09:15am").  My guess is that you're probably using "date", where you mean to use "datetime".

Comment: PS: java.util.date means either "date" or "datetime".  java.sql.date is only "date".  And for databases like MS Sql Server, "date" or "datetime" is DIFFERENT from "timestamp".  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305973/java-util-date-vs-java-sql-date

Comment: PPS: In MS Sql Server (if that's what you're using), a "timestamp" is emphatically NOT a date or datetime:  http://www.sqlteam.com/article/timestamps-vs-datetime-data-types.  If you want a date (irrespective of time of day), make your SQL column "date".  If you want time of day (irrespective of calendar date), make it "time".  Under NO CIRCUMSTANCES use a SQL Server "timestamp" to hold logical time/date columns.

Comment: then i can not save date and time in the same column as i mentioned above 2007-02-07 17:29:46.00? must i separate them into two columns?  By the way i am using ms sql server

Comment: Noooooo!  It means if you want to save "2007-02-07 17:29", then you should define the column in MSSQL as "datetime".  If you want to save only "2007-02-07", then you should define the column as MSSQL "date".  Java's "java.sql.Date" is date-only.  Java's "java.util.Date" does both date and date/time. And MSSQL "timestamp" is NEITHER date nor time - avoid MSSQL timestamp unless you KNOW you need it.  Q: Are you using MS Sql Server?  Or are you using a different database (e.g. DB2 or MySQL)?

Comment: I am using ms sql. I did it wich a bit difficult way. I make stored procedure with takes param also date as string then converts it and inserts. Bad way. lool

Comment: However i can not use java.util.Date with ps.setDate().

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`java.sql.Date` represents a date, not a date and time. From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html):

> To conform with the definition of SQL DATE, the millisecond values wrapped by a java.sql.Date instance must be 'normalized' by setting the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero in the particular time zone with which the instance is associated.

If you want to store a date and time, you should look for another type - e.g. [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html). EDIT: That's not suggesting you use a TIMESTAMP column type - as paulsm4 says in the comments, that's a different thing. However, as far as I can see, JDBC only supports:

- `Date` (no, you want a time too)
- `Time` (no, you want a date too)
- `Timestamp` (includes a date and time, but you don't want TIMESTAMP SQL semantics)

I would *expect* using the Java `Timestamp` type with a DATETIME column to work, although without the level of precision that `Timestamp` provides.

EDIT: After a bit more research, it looks like you *may* want to use the `java.sql.Time` type, but with special driver parameters - at least if you're using the Microsoft driver. See these docs on [configuring JDBC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff427224.aspx) for more information.

Comment: then how to reach to this date? Is there any other option?

Comment: @elbek: See my edit - basically, don't use `Date` here, use a different type.

Comment: if i do the column type timestamp i can not change it manually?

Comment: when i do with timestamp i got this error: Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column. Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the timestamp column, or insert a DEFAULT into the timestamp column.

Comment: @elbek: You should try using a DATETIME column, but java.sql.Timestamp as the Java type.

Comment: @elbek: You've got to start being more precise. Whenever you get an error, tell us what that error is.

Comment: @elbek: If it's talking about a TIMESTAMP column, then you clearly *haven't* followed my suggestion of using a DATETIME column instead.

Comment: @elbek: No, chat doesn't work well for my workflow I'm afraid.

Comment: Yeah i am using date time in db and even i can create the value like that: 12/16/2011 9:12:00 PM in db, But my problem is i can not create this value through the jdbc using preparedStatements

Comment: @elbek: See my latest edit, which should give you some more information - although it's specific to the MS JDBC driver. Which driver are you using?

Comment: i downloaded it from site of microsfot: com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc

Comment: @elbek: So if you're using the Microsoft JDBC driver, you should be able to use `Time` as described in the link near the bottom of my answer. You shouldn't have to resort to using strings.

Comment: @elbek: "The JDBC driver has been designed specifically to use features introduced with SQL Server 2005, but it is backward-compatible with SQL Server 2000, including the 64-bit version. JDBC Driver 3.0 supports the new date and time types, large user-defined types, and sparse columns in SQL Server 2008." (From the System Requirements for the 3.0 drivers.)

Comment: Modern comment: JDBC 4.2 supports `java.time` types, for example with the `PreparedStatement.setObject` method and the `ResultSet.getObject` method. We no longer need to use the old `java.sql` types, but may use `Instant`, `LocalDate`, `LocalTime`, `LocalDateTime` and friends.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

You are likely confused by not understanding that `java.util.Date` is a date-with-time type while its subclass `java.sql.Date` *pretends* to be a date-only class but actually has its time-of-day set to zero. Bloody awful design. Avoid both these classes entirely. Use *java.time* classes only.

For a date-only column in your database, define the column as the SQL-standard `DATE` type.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject(
    … ,
    LocalDateTime.parse( "2007-02-07 17:29:46.00".replace( " " , "T" ) )
    .toLocalDate()
)
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes added to Java 8 and later.

> When I insert a SQL DateTime to the database I get 2007-02-07 12:00:00.00

There is no such thing as a SQL-standard type as `DateTime`, nor any such class in Java. So I do not know your intention there.

As for the input string, `2007-02-07 17:29:46.00`, parse that as a `LocalDateTime` because it lacks any indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC.

That SQL-style format almost complies with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. To fully comply, replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T`. The *java.time* classes use the ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

```
String input = "2007-02-07 17:29:46.00".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
```

Parse.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

A `LocalDateTime` does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. It represents potential moments along a range of about 26-27 hours.

Standard SQL does offer a data type for such a value, `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`.

### Smart objects, not dumb strings

Your entire approach is misguided, wrangling text and using the legacy date-time classes. Instead, exchange *java.time* objects.

As of JDBC 4.2, you need not ever use the troublesome old java.sql types such as `java.sql.Date` or `java.sql.Timestamp`. You can directly exchange java.time objects with your database via `setObject`/`getObject` methods.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ldt ) ;
```

And retrieval.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

If you are trying to work with date-only values, use the SQL-standard type `DATE` and the Java class `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = ldt.toLocalDate() ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

> How to get the value of the seconds in the database

Not sure what you mean by "value of the seconds".

Perhaps you want a count of seconds from the [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) of first moment of 1970 in UTC.

```
long secondsSinceEpoch = ldt.toEpochSecond() ;
```

If your goal was merely to instantiate a `java.sql.Date`, don’t bother. Never use that class again. But, FYI, your specific issue is likely a side-effect of the awful design used for that class. The `java.sql.Date` class inherits from `java.util.Date` which is a date-with-time type. The `java.sql.Date` class *pretends* to be a date-only value, but actually has its time-of-day set to 00:00:00. Even worse, the documentation tells us to ignore the fact of its being a subclass. Don’t bother trying to understand it; just use *java.time* instead.

If you are trying to work with the time-of-day alone, extract a `LocalTime` object.

```
LocalTime lt = ldt.toLocalTime() ;
```

If you want to set the time-of-day to zeros, then you likely want a date-only value. If so, use the `LocalDate` class for a date value without a time-of-day and without a time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = ldt.toLocalDate() :
```

If you do want the first moment of the day on that date, call [`LocalDate::atStartOfDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay()).

```
LocalDateTime ldtStart = ldt.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay() ;
```

**BEWARE:** If you are trying to track actual moments, specific points on the timeline, then all this code above is wrong. Search Stack Overflow to learn about `Instant`, `ZoneId`, and `ZonedDateTime` classes. Search both Stack Overflow and dba.StackExchange.com to learn about the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Re: the Joda recommendation to migrate to `java.time`, here is a quote from their page as of today:
**"Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project."**