# Updation mysql date column using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

while updating datetime field using new `Date()` function, it having date part but it time part will be `(00.00.00`), Insertion it does,t have any problem `2013-08-02 12:57:09` ,but in updation it works like `2013-08-02 00:00:00`....

```
session.createQuery(
"update DeviceDetails u set u.statusUpDate=:statusUpDate where u.id=:dID")
.setDate("statusUpDate", new Date())
.setInteger("dID",dID).executeUpdate();

session.getTransaction().commit()
```

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530545/java-sql-date-time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setTimestamp()`, and not `setDate()`.

Or don't use a query at all: get the entity using `Session.get()`, and modify its fields.

Comment: Why are you repeating the code you already have in your question in this comment?

Comment: I am really interest to know the difference between setDate(),setTimestamp().

Comment: setDate() uses a java.sql.Date (which doesn't have a time portion), whereas setTimestamp() uses a java.sql.Timestamp (which has a time portion). Read the javadoc of those two classes to know the exact difference.

Comment: AM using hibernate query to save the date and time...It working perfectly on saving the session object            checkAdd.setcheck(newDate());                  session.save(checkAdd);            session.getTransaction().commit();                               Once using update it working with date part not in time part...         Actually the problem solved by using setTimestamp() function.Is the mentioned problem occurs because of the java library file

Comment: The problem occurs because you're using setDate(), which means: set the value of the parameter with this date without time value.