# String to Date Java

Tags: java, sql, datetime, jdbc, time

I am trying to  convert the string "5/23/14 02:23:24" from a String in Eclipse to a Date to insert into a SQL statement. The code I have is as follows:

```
String dateAndTime = "5/23/14 02:23:24";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss");
Date date = sdf.parse(dateAndTime);
long dateLong = date.getTime();
insertStatement.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(dateLong));
```

I expect to see

```
23-MAY-2014 2.23.24.000000000 PM
```

in my table, but instead I see

```
23-MAY-2014 12.00.00.000000000 AM
```

Can anyone shed some light on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: [java.util.Date vs java.sql.Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305973/java-util-date-vs-java-sql-date)

Comment: Check this answer by Jon. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530545/java-sql-date-time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A standard `DATE` SQL type doesn't have any time information associated with it, so [the javadocs for `java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) state:

> To conform with the definition of SQL DATE, the millisecond values wrapped by a java.sql.Date instance must be 'normalized' by setting the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero in the particular time zone with which the instance is associated.

You'll want to use a [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) instead.  It corresponds to the SQL type `TIMESTAMP`, which holds date and time of day data.

Answer (score 6):

You're calling `setDate`, which uses a [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html). That represents *just a date*, not a date and time.

You should consider using `setTimestamp` instead, with a [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html). (There may be other ways of doing it for your specific database, but that's probably the simplest general solution):

```
long dateLong = date.getTime();
insertStatement.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(dateLong));
```

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using modern date-time API:**

1. Parse the date-time string into `LocalDateTime`:

```
String dateAndTime = "5/23/14 02:23:24";
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/uu H:m:s", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(dateAndTime, dtf);
```

2. Set the instance of `LocalDateTime` into the database using [`PreparedStatement#setObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject-int-java.lang.Object-):

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO mytable (columnfoo) VALUES (?)");
st.setObject(1, ldt);
st.executeUpdate();
st.close();
```

3. In order to read it from the database, use [`Resultset#getObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject-int-java.lang.Class-):

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ...");
while (rs.next()) {
   LocalDateTime ldt = rs.getObject(1, LocalDateTime.class));
   System.out.println(ldt);
}
rs.close();
st.close();
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>