# NullPointerException on calling ResultSet.getDate()

Tags: java, jdbc

I am getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` on calling `ResultSet.getDate()` in the following code. The entry in the database, however, doesn't seem to be `null`. The connection seems to be active, since other fields are being fetched.
What am I doing wrong?

```
try {
    ... /* Code that creates a connection and initializes statement */

    String query = "SELECT * FROM groups WHERE id = 'testGroup1'";
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
    if(rs.next()) {
        admin = rs.getString("admin_id");
        User.process(admin);
        java.sql.Date created_on = rs.getDate("created_on");
        System.out.println("Created on = " + created_on.toString());
    }
}
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Stuck here");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here's the output and the stack trace:

```
Admin id = 42          // User.process prints the admin id
Stuck here
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.findColumn(ResultSet.java:966)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getDate(ResultSet.java:1988)
    at com.myapp.server.model.Group.initInfo(Group.java:39)
    ...
```

I have the following schema:

```
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                | varchar(50)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| admin_id          | varchar(50)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| created_on        | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

And the following entry in the database:

```
+------------+----------+---------------------+
| id         | admin_id | created_on          |
+------------+----------+---------------------+
| testGroup1 | 42       | 2014-12-15 22:46:31 |
+------------+----------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Could you try rs.getTimestamp();

Comment: I think the issue will be with the SQL date format. Is the `datetime` a proper datatype you are referring? Try `Date` instead.

Comment: @SemihEker `getTimestamp()` also throws `NullPointerException`.

Comment: It seems like a bug in your jdbc driver. What is the version you are using? Recent mysql drivers do not even have a class called `ResultSet`

Comment: @Dima I was using `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8`. I've upgraded to `mysql-connector-java-5.1.34` which does seem to have a `ResultSet` class. It now shows a `java.sql.SQLException` saying `Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found `User.process` further queried the database thereby closing the current `ResultSet`.

Comment: Like @SemihEker suggested, `getTimestamp()` eventually gives me the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162753/jdbc-resultset-i-need-a-getdatetime-but-there-is-only-getdate-and-gettimestamp),could you try sthg like that;

I take the code also from the question I mentioned above.

```
Timestamp timestamp = resultSet.getTimestamp(i);
if (timestamp != null)
    date = new java.util.Date(timestamp.getTime()));
```

Comment: `getTimestamp()` also gives the same error, like I mentioned in the comment. Getting a `NullPointerException` on `rs.getTimestamp("created_on")`.

Comment: You said that "Like @SemihEker suggested, getTimestamp() eventually gives me the desired result. ". Is this answer ok for you?

Comment: Yes, once I get rid of the NPE. [The error](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27490261/1492578) was in the `User.process` function. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The Type of the field `created_on`in your database is `datetime`, this is not the same as the Java `Date`

You'll need to convert it.

If you look at the first answer at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530545/java-sql-date-time) you'll see how to fix it

Comment: Thanks for the link. Using `getTimestamp()` gives me the desired result, once I get rid of the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: The conversion from a `datetime` (equivalent to a timestamp) is automatic and required by the JDBC specification (it will simply drop the time)

Answer (score 2):

I found `User.process` further queried the database thereby closing the current `ResultSet` (or so I speculate). The `NullPointerException` goes away when I do the following:

```
try {
    ...
    if(rs.next()) {
        admin = rs.getString("admin_id");
        java.sql.Timestamp created_on = rs.getTimestamp("created_on");
        User.process(admin);
    }
}
catch(Exception e) {
    ...
}
```

Also using `getTimestamp()` as suggested by other solutions gets me the desired result.