# Convert java.util.Date to java.sql.Date with 'yyyy-mm-dd hh mm ss'

Tags: java, json, datetime, jackson

I need to pass json string to one of the rest web service. There is a property called 'amortizationdate' which will have format 'yyyy-mm-dd hh mm ss'.

for e.g. {amortizationdate:2015-07-31 00:00:00}

we are having AmortizationVO.java with a property amortizationdate.

for e.g

```
private java.sql.Date amortizationDate.

public void setAmortizationDate(java.sql.Date  date){

}
```

We need to set the date by calling `setAmortizationDate(..date)` method and using Jackson to convert AmortizationVO.java to Json.

but in JSON I m getting {amortizationdate:2015-07-31}. But expected result should be with timestamp.(amortizationdate:2015-07-31 00:00:00)

note: I don't want to use util date in my Value Object.

Pls help.

What I've tried:

```
java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Timestamp sq = new java.sql.Timestamp(utilDate.getTime());


ExcelEntityAddressVO entityAddressVO = new ExcelEntityAddressVO();      
entityAddressVO.setAmortizationDate(new java.sql.Date(sq.getTime()));
```

This is my JSON:

```
{
  "amortizationdate" : "2015-07-31",
}
```

Comment: sql.Date does not have time information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8530574/4136325

Answer (score 1):

You don't want `java.sql.Date` - it doesn't keep time, use `java.sql.Timestamp`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class Test {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
            java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
            System.out.println("utilDate:" + utilDate);
            Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(utilDate.getTime());
            System.out.println(ts);
       }
}
```