# SQL database (JDBC): A column of type date only stores date values and not time values

Tags: java, rest, date, datetime, jdbc

I have a database like this where `lastEdited` is a `date` field.

[image]

I connected this database to a Java web application by using "RESTFUL web-services from database"

This automatically generated a class called ThreadChat for my `THREADCHAT` column. Given here is the getter and setter for the lastEdited part.

lastEdited is a java.util.Date object.

```
public Date getLastedited() {
    return lastedited;
}

public void setLastedited(Date lastedited) {
    this.lastedited = lastedited;
}
```

Here, I am creating a new ThreadChat object and adding the data to the database. Argument for lastEdited is a java.util.Date object.

```
    ThreadChat thread = new ThreadChat(threadName, new Date(), loginIdInt);
    threadChatFacadeREST.create(thread);
```

This would update the table like this.

[image]

This method returns all the records in the THREADCHAT table.

```
List<ThreadChat> list = getAllThreads();
```

However, `getLastEdited()` returns a `XMLGregorianCalender` object instead of a `Date` object as in the getter method above.

[image]

If I print this object to the console, the date part is there but I get 00:00 for the minutes and hours part every time.

```
2018-04-10T00:00:00+05:30
```

How do I store Date + Time in a JDBC database and retrieve both?

Comment: So, a really quick search of [SQL data types](https://www.google.com.au/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=sql+datatypes&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=6pPMWqq8Ls3N8gekgaqwCw) provides a number of really interesting results. Just of the first hit - *"DATE() A date. Format: YYYY-MM-DD"*, well that explains a bit, but perhaps *"DATETIME() *A date and time combination. Format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS"* would be more useful

Comment: You don't seem  to have asked a question here.  What's the actual problem?  Oh, and a DATE is just a date.  A DATETIME is a date and a time.  That's how it's _supposed_ to be.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I want to store and retrieve the time along with the date.

Comment: Possible duplicate [java sql date time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530545/java-sql-date-time)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I didn't use java.sql.date.  Used java.util.date which stores both date and time.

Comment: @Enzio Which is irrelevant - because it's about how the database stores the value, not how Java represents it. SQL date type ONLY stores date information, it doesn't store time information, so when you load it into Java, bang, time is zeroed out - use the correct data type in the database

Comment: @Enzio Java's new Date/Time API has similar concept (`LocalDate`, `LocalTime`, `LocalDateTime`) which provides structures to mange the elements you're most interested in, SQL just did it first, along time ago

Comment: Most of the information here are not needed. Basically you have table with a `DATE` column type, you get that value in a POJO and you only get a `Date` with the time unit. I don't see what is the point with most of the information above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

You are using a **date-only [type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type) to hold a date-time value** – trying to fit a [square peg into a round hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_peg_in_a_round_hole).

> How do I store Date + Time in a JDBC database and retrieve both?

To store a moment, a date-time value, use a date-time type:

- `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` in your database.
- `Instant` in Java.

You are using terribly confusing legacy classes. Use only *java.time* classes instead.

## Databases vary

Databases vary widely in their date-time [data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type) and their behavior. You do not specify your database, so we can only guess or abide by the [SQL standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL).

The SQL standard barely touches on the subject of date-time handling, unfortunately. The standard briefly defines:

- `DATE` as a date-only value without time-of-day.
- A `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` is a date and a time-of-day, but lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC, so it does *not* represent actual moments.
- For actual moments, use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. That type name can be misleading as some implementations such as [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) do not store a zone with the value, but instead use any passed zone information to adjust into a [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) value for storage.

## java.time

You are using terrible old date-time classes from the earliest versions of Java. Those were supplanted in Java 8 and later by the *java.time* classes. Never use `Date` or `Calendar` again.

Generally best to think, work, store, log, and exchange date-time values in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) unless specifically required by the business logic or user-interface. So generally you should focus on the `Instant` class. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction). This class replaces `java.util.Date`.

Capture the current moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
```

Store this `Instant` in a database column of SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` or whatever is akin to that in your particular database.

### JDBC 4.2

As of JDBC 4.2 and later, you can directly exchange *java.time* objects with your database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

### Converting

If handed an obsolete [`XMLGregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html), immediately convert into *java.time* `ZonedDateTime` by way of the obsolete [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) class.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = myXmlGregCal.toGregorianCalendar().toZonedDateTime() ;  // Convert from legacy classes to modern java.time class.
```

If you want to see that same moment in UTC rather than the wall-clock time used by the people of that particular region (time zone), extract an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;  // Adjust from zoned moment to UTC. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.
```

If you must inter-operate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, you can convert back and forth. Tip: Try to stay within *java.time* as much as possible. The legacy classes are an awful mess of poor design.

```
java.util.Date myJavaUtilDate = java.util.Date.from( instant ) ;
```

And, going the other direction.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

The type of your field in your database is `DATE` so `DATE` only stores `YYYY-MM-DD`.

If you want to store also the time you must change the type of your field in your database to `DATETIME`. The representation of this is: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS`

More information in: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp

Comment: I ended up using timestamp. I selected your answer because of the  explanation and provided sources.

Comment: You should clarify your answer as to “DATETIME. The format of this is: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS”. Databases do not have a “format“ in their stored date-time values, only textual representations such as input/output has a format.

Comment: When i said format i would say representation, sorry but my english isn't very good.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a DATA_TYPE TIMESTAMP. You should change your Database if you can.