# how to map java.util.Date to MySql Date in Ibatis when I take input through JSON

Tags: java, mysql, json, ibatis, mybatis

I am taking date of birth as input using JSON

```
{"dateOfBirth":"1973-08-26"}
```

This field exists in `Person.java` class

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Person {

    Date dateOfBirth;

    //Some other fields

    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {

         this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
       }

   public Date getDateOfBirth() {

        return dateOfBirth;
       }
   }
```

This is mapped to person table in mysql database.
I am querying the database like:

```
entityId = (Long) session.selectOne("ValidatePerson", registerUserRequestParams);
```

Following are the entries I am making in my mapper.xml

```
<select id="ValidatePerson" parameterMap="ValidatePersonMap" resultType="long">
    select person.entityId
    from person
    where 
                //Some other Validation checks
        <if test="dateOfBirth != null">
        and person.dateOfBirth = #{dateOfBirth}
         </if>
        );
</select>
```

I have a prameter Map as

```
<parameterMap id="ValidatePersonMap" type="java.util.HashMap">
     <parameter property="dateOfBirth" javaType="java.util.Date" jdbcType="DATE"  mode="IN"/>
</parameterMap>
```

I am not able to get any result from database.It does not select any row even though value exists.I have checked that none of other validation checks are failing. If I pass dateOfBirth as null in JSON then then I get result.

I have also written a test case and setting request as follows:

```
Date dob = new Date(73,7,26);
request.setDateOfBirth(dob);
```

When I pass values from test case as mentioned above I get result from database.
Problem occurs only when i get request parameters using json.

- The format of JSOn and the format stored in DB are same
- One work around I have is to manually convert java.util.Date to String in above format and pass it as string. But this is pretty bad approach and client would not like it.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2306051/579580

Answer (score 1):

Use [Timestamp](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html). Consider [Joda time plug](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). ...and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2306051/579580) answer.

These three will absolutely do the magic.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried formatting the java date. Maybe the formats are different so it can't match between the JSON and the one stored in your db?

Comment: the formats are same in JSON and DB... this JSON is produced using gson library...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

mysql attribute type is `Timestamp`
and I format the date for JSON in Java like this:

```
Date d = new Date();
java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String sd = sdf.format(d);
java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM:ss");
String fakeit =sd+"T"+sdf2.format(d);
```

I then use `fakeit`