# Timezones in SQL DATE vs java.sql.Date

Tags: java, sql, date, jdbc, timezone

I'm getting a bit confused by the behaviour of the SQL DATE data type vs. that of `java.sql.Date`. Take the following statement, for example:

```sql
select cast(? as date)           -- in most databases
select cast(? as date) from dual -- in Oracle
```

Let's prepare and execute the statement with Java

```java
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(0)); // GMT 1970-01-01 00:00:00
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
rs.next();

// I live in Zurich, which is CET, not GMT. So the following prints -3600000, 
// which is CET 1970-01-01 00:00:00
// ... or   GMT 1969-12-31 23:00:00
System.out.println(rs.getDate(1).getTime());
```

In other words, the GMT timestamp I bind to the statement becomes the CET timestamp I get back. At what step is the timezone added and why?

Note:

- I have observed this to be true for any of these databases:

  DB2, Derby, H2, HSQLDB, Ingres, MySQL, Oracle, Postgres, SQL Server, Sybase ASE, Sybase SQL Anywhere
- I have observed this to be false for SQLite (which doesn't really have true `DATE` data types)
- All of this is irrelevant when using `java.sql.Timestamp` instead of `java.sql.Date`
- This is a similar question, which doesn't answer this question, however: [java.util.Date vs java.sql.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305973/java-util-date-vs-java-sql-date)

Comment: I am not too sure, but the only thing I see is, its getting  converted to the current timezone while calling getTime() method.

Comment: @novice_at_work: how is that? `new java.sql.Date(0).getTime()` yields `0`. No timezone issues there...? The conversion must be done within the JDBC driver or in the database.

Comment: When you say `new Date(0)` above, is that a `java.sql.Date` or `java.util.Date`?

Comment: @AdamRofer: Clarified. BTW, there is no `PreparedStatement.setDate(int, java.util.Date)` method... ;-)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The [JDBC specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jdbc-4_1-mrel-spec/index.html) does not define any details with regards to time zone. Nonetheless, most of us know the pains of having to deal with JDBC time zone discrepencies; just look at all the [StackOverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jdbc+time+zone)!

Ultimately, the handling of time zone for date/time database types boils down to the database server, the JDBC driver and everything in between. You're even at the mercy of JDBC driver bugs; PostgreSQL fixed a [bug in version 8.3](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/changes.html#N10600) where

> Statement.getTime, .getDate, and .getTimestamp methods which are passed a Calendar object were rotating the timezone in the wrong direction.

When you create a new date using `new Date(0)` (let's assert you are using Oracle JavaSE [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html), your date is created

> using the given milliseconds time value. If the given milliseconds value contains time information, the driver will set the time components to the time in the default time zone (the time zone of the Java virtual machine running the application) that corresponds to zero GMT.

So, `new Date(0)` should be using GMT.

When you call [`ResultSet.getDate(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDate%28int%29), you're executing a JDBC implementation. The JDBC specification does not dictate how a JDBC implementation should handle time zone details; so you're at the mercy of the implementation. Looking at the Oracle 11g [`oracle.sql.DATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/DATE.html) JavaDoc, it doesn't seem Oracle DB stores time zone information, so it performs its own conversions to get the date into a `java.sql.Date`. I have no experience with Oracle DB, but I would guess the JDBC implementation is using the server's and your local JVM's time zone settings to do the conversion from `oracle.sql.DATE` to `java.sql.Date`.

---

You mention that multiple RDBMS implementations handle time zone correctly, with the exception of SQLite. Let's look at how [H2](http://www.h2database.com/) and [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) work when you send date values to the JDBC driver and when you get date values from the JDBC driver.

The H2 JDBC driver [`PrepStmt.setDate(int, Date)`](https://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/main/org/h2/jdbc/JdbcPreparedStatement.java#359) uses [`ValueDate.get(Date)`](https://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/main/org/h2/value/ValueDate.java#56), which calls [`DateTimeUtils.dateValueFromDate(long)`](https://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/main/org/h2/util/DateTimeUtils.java#732) which does a time zone conversion.

Using this [SQLite JDBC driver](https://code.google.com/p/sqlite-jdbc/), [`PrepStmt.setDate(int, Date)`](https://code.google.com/p/sqlite-jdbc/source/browse/src/main/java/org/sqlite/PrepStmt.java#283) calls [`PrepStmt.setObject(int, Object)`](https://code.google.com/p/sqlite-jdbc/source/browse/src/main/java/org/sqlite/PrepStmt.java#221) and does not do any time zone conversion.

The H2 JDBC driver [`JdbcResultSet.getDate(int)`](https://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/main/org/h2/jdbc/JdbcResultSet.java#344) returns `get(columnIndex).getDate()`. [`get(int)`](https://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/main/org/h2/jdbc/JdbcResultSet.java#2950) returns an H2 [`Value`](https://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/main/org/h2/value/Value.java) for the specified column. Since the column type is `DATE`, H2 uses [`ValueDate`](https://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/main/org/h2/value/ValueDate.java). [`ValueDate.getDate()`](https://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/main/org/h2/value/ValueDate.java#80) calls [`DateTimeUtils.convertDateValueToDate(long)`](https://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/main/org/h2/util/DateTimeUtils.java#628), which ultimately creates a `java.sql.Date` after a time zone conversion.

Using this [SQLite JDBC driver](https://code.google.com/p/sqlite-jdbc/), the [`RS.getDate(int)`](https://code.google.com/p/sqlite-jdbc/source/browse/src/main/java/org/sqlite/RS.java#265) code is much simpler; it just returns a `java.sql.Date` using the `long` date value stored in the database.

So we see that the H2 JDBC driver is being smart about handling time zone conversions with dates while the SQLite JDBC driver is not (not to say this decision isn't smart, it might suit SQLite design decisions well). If you chase down the source for the other RDBMS JDBC drivers you mention, you will probably find that most are approaching date and time zone in a similar fashion as how H2 does.

Though the JDBC specifications do not detail time zone handling, it makes good sense that RDBMS and JDBC implementation designers took time zone into consideration and will handle it properly; especially if they want their products to be marketable in the global arena. These designers are pretty darn smart and I am not surprised that most of them get this right, even in the absence of a concrete specification.

---

I found this Microsoft SQL Server blog, [Using time zone data in SQL Server 2008](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2008/03/18/using-time-zone-data-in-sql-server-2008.aspx), which explains how time zone complicates things:

> timezones are a complex area and each application will need to address how you are going to handle time zone data to make programs more user friendly.
>
> Unfortunately, there is no current international standard authority for timezone names and values.  Each system needs to use a system of their own choosing, and until there is an international standard, it is not feasible to try to have SQL Server provide one, and would ultimately cause more problems than it would solve.

Comment: So essentially, you're saying that the fact that all of my 11 test databases (except SQLite) behave the same way is a mere coincidence, or "accidental compatibility", and it isn't specified? I hope not!? However, I agree with your rationale and you're probably right, too, but I find this a bit frightening... :-)

Comment: Jeez, I like your post less and less. Bring me some good news! ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, date/time RDBMS types can be a real pain when you actually have to deal with multiple time zones. Especially when you throw legacy applications into the mix ... and they don't deal with time zone.

Comment: SQL Server JDBC 4.0/4.1 drivers adjust `datetime` column value as if DB hold local to client time. This leads to error if you actually  assume that DB hold UTC values. See my investigation at http://stackoverflow.com/a/29705750/173149  Global setting `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+00:00"));` help  to work with DB dates as them in UTC.

Answer (score 13):

It is the jdbc driver that does the conversion.  It needs to convert the Date object to a format acceptable by the db/wire format and when that format doesn't include a time zone, the tendency is to default to the local machine's time zone setting when interpreting the date.  So, most likely scenario, given the list of drivers you specify, is that you set the date to GMT 1970-1-1 00:00:00 but the interpreted date when you set it to the statement was CET 1970-1-1 1:00:00.  Since the date is only the date portion, you get 1970-1-1 (without a time zone) sent to the server and echoed back to you.  When the driver gets the date back, and you access it as a date,  it sees 1970-1-1 and interprets that again with the local time zone, i.e. CET 1970-1-1 00:00:00 or GMT 1969-12-31 23:00:00.  Hence, you have "lost" an hour compared to the original date.

Comment: That is the most likely explanation, yes

Comment: @philwb   Can u tell me which JDBC driver should i use,please...Right now i am using com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Answer (score 6):

Both java.util.Date and the Oracle/MySQL Date objects are simply representations of a point in time regardless of location. This means that it is very likely to be internally stored as the number of milli/nano seconds since the "epoch", GMT 1970-01-01 00:00:00.

When you read from the resultset, your call to "rs.getDate()" tells the resultset to take the internal data containing the point in time, and convert it to a java Date object. This date object is created on your local machine, so Java will choose your local timezone, which is CET for Zurich.

The difference you are seeing is a difference in representation, not a difference in time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Essentially, this is a short version of what has been said already

Comment: Note that `ResultSet.getDate()` produces a `java.sql.Date` not a `java.util.Date`.  Also note that `java.sql.Date` is defined to truncate its internal timestamp to midnight GMT, so if the time given to it is in a timezone that is not GMT the result may differ.

Answer (score 5):

The class `java.sql.Date` corresponds to SQL DATE, which does not store time or timezone information. The way this is accomplished is by 'normalizing' the date, like the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) puts it:

> To conform with the definition of SQL DATE, the millisecond values wrapped by a java.sql.Date instance must be 'normalized' by setting the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero in the particular time zone with which the instance is associated.

This means that when you work in UTC+1 and ask the database for a DATE a compliant implementation does exactly what you've observed: return a java.sql.Date with a milliseconds value that corresponds to the date in question *at 00:00:00 UTC+1* independently of how the data got to the database in the first place.

Database drivers may allow changing this behaviour through options if it's not what you want.

On the other hand, when you pass a `java.sql.Date` to the database, the driver will use the default time zone to separate the date and time components from the millisecond value. If you use `0` and you're in UTC+X, the date will be 1970-01-01 for X>=0 and 1969-12-31 for X<0.

---

Sidenote: It's odd to see that the documentation for the [`Date(long)` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) differs from the implementation. The javadoc says this:

> If the given milliseconds value contains time information, the driver will set the time components to the time in the default time zone (the time zone of the Java virtual machine running the application) that corresponds to zero GMT.

However what is actually implemented in OpenJDK is this:

```
public Date(long date) {
    // If the millisecond date value contains time info, mask it out.
    super(date);

}
```

Apparently this "masking out" is not implemented. Just as well because the specified behaviour is not well specified, e.g. should 1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT-6 = 1970-01-01 06:00:00 GMT be mapped to 1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT = 1969-12-31 18:00:00 GMT-6, or to 1970-01-01 18:00:00 GMT-6?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I somewhat overlooked the class-level Javadoc, which is a bit of a contradiction with the constructor Javadoc...

Answer (score 3):

### JDBC 4.2 and java.time

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setObject(1, LocalDate.EPOCH); // The epoch year LocalDate, '1970-01-01'.
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
rs.next();

// It doesnt matter where you live or your JVM’s time zone setting
// since a LocalDate doesn’t have or use time zone
System.out.println(rs.getObject(1, LocalDate.class));
```

I didn’t test, but unless there’s a bug in your JDBC driver, the output in all time zones is:

> 1970-01-01

`LocalDate` is a date without time of day and without time zone. So there is no millisecond value to get and no time of day to be confused about. `LocalDate` is part of java.time, the modern Java date and time API. JDBC 4.2 specifies that you can transfer java.time objects including `LocalDate` to and from your SQL database through the methods `setObject` and `getObject` I use in the snippet (so not `setDate` nor `getDate`).

I think that virtually all of us are using JDBC 4.2 drivers by now.

### What went wrong in your code?

`java.sql.Date` is a hack trying (not very successfully) to disguise a `java.util.Date` as a date without time of day. I recommend that you don’t use that class.

From the documentation:

> To conform with the definition of SQL `DATE`, the millisecond values
>   wrapped by a `java.sql.Date` instance must be 'normalized' by setting
>   the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero in the
>   particular time zone with which the instance is associated.

“Associated” may be vague. What this means, I believe, is that the millisecond value must denote the start of day in your JVM’s default time zone (Europe/Zurich in your case, I suppose). So when you create `new java.sql.Date(0)` equal to GMT 1970-01-01 00:00:00, it’s really you creating an incorrect `Date` object, since this time is 01:00:00 in your time zone. JDBC is ignoring the time of day (we might have expected an error message, but don’t get any). So SQL is getting and returning a date of 1970-01-01. JDBC correctly translates this back to a `Date` containing CET 1970-01-01 00:00:00. Or a millisecond value of -3 600 000. Yes, it’s confusing. As I said, don’t use that class.

If you had been at a negative GMT offset (for example most time zones in the Americas), `new java.sql.Date(0)` would have been interpreted as 1969-12-31, so this would have been the date you had passed to and got back from SQL.

To make matters worse, think what happens when the JVM’s time zone setting is changed. Any part of your program and any other program running in the same JVM may do this at any time. This typically causes all `java.sql.Date` objects created before the change to become invalid and may sometimes shift their date by one day (in rare cases by two days).

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [JSR-000221 JDBC™ API Specification 4.2 Maintenance Release 2](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jdbc-4_2-mrel2-spec/)
- [Documentation of `java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html)

Answer (score 2):

There is an overload of `getDate` that accepts a `Calendar`, could using this solve your problem? Or you could use a `Calendar` object to convert the information.

That is, assuming that retrieval is the problem.

```
Calendar gmt = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setDate(1, new Date(0)); // I assume this is always GMT
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
rs.next();

//This will output 0 as expected
System.out.println(rs.getDate(1, gmt).getTime());
```

Alternatively, assuming that storage is the problem.

```
Calendar gmt = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
gmt.setTimeInMillis(0) ;
stmt.setDate(1, gmt.getTime()); //getTime returns a Date object
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
rs.next();

//This will output 0 as expected
System.out.println(rs.getDate(1).getTime());
```

I don't have a test environment for this, so you will have to find out which is the correct assumption. Also I believe that `getTime` returns the current locale, otherwise you will have to look up how to do a quick timezone conversion.

Comment: The question isn't really about getting around this "issue", but rather about understanding the rationale of this seemingly undocumented JDBC "feature". So unfortunately, I don't know whether retrieval or storage is "the problem"...

Comment: @LukasEder: I would say both. JDBC should uniformly store and retrieve information from the DB. Either assume GMT, or assume local time zone, don't do one then the other. It seems that either `new Date(0)` or `getDate` is assigning the local time zone while the other is using GMT.