# Selecting columns from multiple tables in hibernate when using aggregrate function

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, hql

I have following schema

`Table: Product 
Columns : 
Product_ID
Product_Name`

`Table: Sales_Detail
Columns : 
Sales_Detail_ID
Product_ID
Quantity
Total_Sales
..
..`

What I want to do is to show the daily sales using the following query. 
`SELECT Prouduct_ID, SUM(sd.Quantity), SUM(sd.Selling_Rate) FROM SalesDetail sd WHERE DATE(Date_Time)=CURDATE() GROUP BY Product_ID`

And get the product name and product id from the result. How do I do that. I went through resources in the internet but non could help me to come to a correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't have Hibernate to test it but this HQL query might be a good start :

```
SELECT
  sd.Product_ID,
  p.Product_Name,
  SUM(sd.Quantity),
  SUM(sd.Selling_Rate)
FROM
  SalesDetail sd
INNER JOIN Product p 
WHERE
  p.Product_ID = sd.Product_ID AND
  sd.Date_Time > CURRENT_DATE()
GROUP BY
  sd.Product_ID, p.Product_Name
```

I don't know where `Date_Time` is coming from but I'm guessing the table `SalesDetail`.

I am not certain than `DATE(Date_Time)` will work so I used `sd.Date_Time > CURRENT_DATE()` but you should probably calculate the time range out of the HQL and instead use something like this `sd.Date_Time BETWEEN :dateTimeStart AND :dateTimeEnd`.  See [HQL to query records between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265134/hql-to-query-records-between-two-dates) for more information on how to bind date parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is what I have done which solved my problem. It was actually easy but tricky one.

The main focus is on the `SELECT` query. Here productHeader is the object of `ProductHeader` class which refers to `product_header` named table in the database. `Product_ID` the primary key of `product_header` table is selected as `productHeader.Product_ID` i.e `(PRODUCT_HEADER_OBJECT.PRIMARY_KEY_ATTRIBUTE)`

```
        Session session = null;
        try{
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();

            /*Query to get the daily sales report. This query will provide current date as input and sum the total product quanitity sold and total sales selling rate*/
            Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT productHeader.Product_ID, SUM(s.Quantity) as Quantity, SUM(Total) FROM SalesDetail s WHERE DATE(Date_Time)=CURDATE() GROUP BY Product_ID");

            List<Object[]> groupList = query.list();
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
            ProductHeader productHeader = new ProductHeader();

            for(Object[] arr : groupList){
                productHeader =null;
                String productID = (String) arr[0]; //the first index in the object array list is productID 
                                                    //as it is the first one defined in the HQL query above
                double quantity = (double) arr[1];
                double totalSales = (double)arr[2];

                session = sessionFactory.openSession();
                session.beginTransaction();

                /*Getting the product header class by passing primary key value to session.get() method*/
                productHeader = (ProductHeader) session.get(ProductHeader.class, productID);
                String productName = productHeader.getProduct_Name();


                DailySales dailySales= new DailySales();
                dailySales.setSn(billSN);
                dailySales.setProductID(productID);
                dailySales.setPrductName(productName);
                dailySales.setQuantitySold(quantity);
                dailySales.setSalesAmount(totalSales);
                data.add(dailySales);

                tblDailySales.setItems(data);
                System.out.println("From object parsing "+Arrays.toString(arr));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error while populating daily sales table : " + e.getMessage());
        }
```