# java.sql.Date in Java 8 compared to Java 6

Tags: java, sql, oracle, date, java-8

I know that a java.sql.Date *should* have hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds set to zero, to comply with the definition of standard SQL date. This is documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) (the same in Java 8).

I also know that the [Oracle DATE type](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF0021) **does have** these time fields of YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, and SECOND. But no fractional second nor time zone.

I noticed that the same query in Java 6 and in Java 8 does not behave the same :

```
private static final String REQUETE_LISTE_CALENDRIER_DATE = 
    " SELECT ID_DATE, JOUR" +
    " FROM CALENDRIER " +
    " WHERE ID_DATE = ? ";
```

Binding to the [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) a java.sql.Date "dateCourante" defined like this (which sets a value to those time fields) :

```
GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(); // "now"
java.sql.Date dateCourante = new java.sql.Date(gregorianCalendar.getTime().getTime()); // date AND time of "now"
```

- with Java 6, I find a value,
- with Java 8, I do not.

In my database, the date has hours, minutes, seconds to zero. We can check with the following query :

```sql
select to_char(id_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
from calendrier
where id_date = to_date('26/08/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

that gives :

> 26/08/2016 00:00:00

So, what I understand, is that :

- in Java 6, the time fields of a [`java.sql.Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) are set to zero before the query is launched on the database, whereas
- in Java 8, the time fields of [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) are left as is in the query.

I have not been able to find documentation about this behavior.

Can anybody confirm or explain that ?

As a workaround, I use this, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650186/choosing-between-java-util-date-or-java-sql-date/24661790#24661790) :
dDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(dDate.toLocalDate()); // where dDate is java.sql.Date

Comment: This depends on the Oracle JDBC **driver** - not the Java version as far as I know. The newer drivers do not comply with the JDBC specs (because Oracle doesn't care about its own specifications): https://community.oracle.com/message/13398818#13398818

Comment: The implementation of `java.sql.Date` doesn't truncate the milliseconds value provide (and iirc it never has); the text in the javadoc is an instruction to driver developers how they must handle it. So likely the problem is how the Oracle driver handles it.

Comment: The above is actually noted in the link referenced in the question: "If the given milliseconds value contains time information, **the driver will set** the time components to the time [...] that corresponds to zero GMT".

Comment: The comments of a_horse_with_no_name and mustaccio seem to make a good answer if taken together.

Answer (score 3):

While I do not have an explanation, except to say many folks have reported problems and violations of JDBC with the latest generations of Oracle drivers, I can say that you are misusing those classes. And better classes are available.

## `java.sql.Date` is date-only

You have selected the wrong class on the Java side. While the [`java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) class does indeed have a time set to `00:00:00` in UTC within its internals, you are supposed to ignore that fact, as instructed by the class documentation. The **`java.sql.Date` is intended for a date-only** value, without a time-of-day and without a time zone.

This class is a poor design, a bad hack, inheriting from `java.util.Date` while telling you to ignore that inheritance fact.

## `java.sql.Timestamp` is date *and* time

The [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) is the type you need in your case rather than [`java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html). (But read on for an even better class.)

The whole bunch of old date-time classes from the earliest versions of Java were a brave industry-first attempt at tackling the problem of date-time handling, but they fell short. They are poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. Avoid them: `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, `java.util.GregorianCalendar`, `java.text.DateFormat`, `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`. And if possible, avoid the java.sql types as well. Instead use the java.time classes.

## JDBC 4.2

As of JDBC 4.2, your JDBC driver may be able to directly access java.time types from your database. The `PreparedStatement::setObject` and `ResultSet::getObject` methods may be able to render your date-time values from the database as java.time objects.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( 1 );
```

…or perhaps…

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( 1 , Instant.class );
```

If your driver is not so capable, then convert *briefly* to the java.sql types and immediately convert to java.time yourself. Do all your business logic using java.time. Resort to java.sql types only for exchanging data with the database. To convert to/from java.time, look for new methods added to the old classes. For example, [`java.sql.Timestamp::toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toInstant--).

Here we extract a `java.sql.Timestamp` from the `ResultSet` and immediately convert it to an `Instant`. You may want to do this on two lines instead of one combined line for debugging purposes.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getTimestamp( 1 ).toInstant();
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation. I knew about the limitations of java.sql.Date, and the use of java.sql.Timesamp. I don't know yet the java.time classes which look very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Java SE 8 also has classes for some other common use cases.

## `YearMonth`

There is the [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html) class, which contains a month and day. Useful for representing birthdays.

## `MonthDay`

The [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class covers the credit card start date and expiration date use cases and scenarios in which people have a date with no specified day.

## JDBC 4.2

JDBC in Java SE 8 will support these new types, but there will be no public JDBC API changes. The existing generic setObject and getObject methods will be sufficient.