# java.time.LocalDate not supported in native queries by latest Spring Data/Hibernate?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-5.x, localdate, jsr310

Problem: Native queries with Spring Data returning dates return java.sql.Date not java.time.LocalDate, despite the setup.

Context: A new project with Spring Boot 2.0.0.M5 (the latest), Hibernate 5.2.11, Hibernate-Java8 5.2.12 (which gives support for JSR310 classes as long as it's on the classpath).

Anonymized example below (the app is not really about birthdays):

```
public interface BirthdayRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID> {
    @Query(value = "select day from birthdays", nativeQuery = true)
    Iterable<java.sql.Date> getBirthdays(); //the return type should ideally be java.time.LocalDate
}
```

In the database (SQL Server), the day field is DATE and values are like 2017-10-24.

**The problem is that at runtime, the Spring Data repository** (whose implementation I cannot control, or is there a way?) **returns `java.sql.Date` not `java.time.LocalDate`** (Clarification: the return type appears to be decided by Spring Data and remains `java.sql.Date` even if I change the return type to be `java.time.LocalDate`, which is how I started to).

**Isn't there a way to get `LocalDate` directly?** I can convert it later, but (1) that's inefficient and (2) the repository methods have to return the old date/time classes, which is something I'd like to avoid. I read the Spring Data [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/), but there's nothing about this.

EDIT: for anyone having the same question, below is the solution, the converter suggested by Jens.

```
public class LocalDateTypeConverter {

    @Converter(autoApply = true)
    public static class LocalDateConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate date) {
            return date == null ? null : new Date(LocalDateToDateConverter.INSTANCE.convert(date).getTime());
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date date) {
            return date == null ? null : DateToLocalDateConverter.INSTANCE.convert(date);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm confused. You specified in your interface that you want `Iterable<java.sql.Date>` why do you expect anything else? Why do "the repository methods have to return the old date/time classes?"

Comment: That's what it gets returned by Spring Data. If I put LocalDate (which I did initially), it fails at runtime with a ClassCastException when I retrieve the item from the iterator. That's why I put that comment, that the type should be. I'll add a clarification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you found a gap in the converters. Spring Data converts out of the box between `java.util.Date` and `java.time.LocalDate` but not between  `java.time.LocalDate` and `java.sql.Date` and other date and time-related types in the `java.sql` package.

You can create your own converter to do that. You can use [Jsr310JpaConverters](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/convert/threeten/Jsr310JpaConverters.java) as a template.

Also, you might want to create a feature request and if you build a converter for your use, you might even submit a pull request.

Comment: Thanks, Jen. Could you please clarify, if known, why Spring Data (or is it the driver) chooses `java.sql.Date` as opposed to, say, `java.util.Date` or `java.time.Date`? The field type in the database is date (which, for SQL Server, is what it says, just YYYY-MM-DD). Out of the 3 posibilities, how is that particular one selected? Also, given that the query is native, how to tell Spring Data to _use_ it for the return type? There's nothing to annotate, like in the case of JPA entities and columns. Thank you.

Comment: Without looking in the code at any detail: Spring Data probably just takes whatever the driver provides as a default and then tries to convert that to the required type with its converters. But in this case a suitable converter is not available.

Comment: I suspect that converter matching logic looks at exactly the same class and not also at subclasses. `java.sql.Date` is a subclass of `java.util.Date` (a useful discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650186/choosing-between-java-util-date-or-java-sql-date) so the converter for the latter should/could activate, but it doesn't. I'll work on the converter then.

Comment: And the converter worked, so I'll accept the answer fully.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an older question, but my solution to this problem does not require a custom converter.

```
    public interface BirthdayRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID> {
      @Query(value = "select cast(day as date) from birthdays", nativeQuery = true)
      Iterable<java.time.LocalDate> getBirthdays();
    }
```

The `CAST` tells JPQL to use available java date\time types rather than java.sql.Date

Comment: Cool! Works very well!