# Which timezone is java.sql.Date toLocalDate using

Tags: java, java-8, java-time, sqldatetime

I'm surprised that `java.sql.Date` has a method `toLocalDate()`.

`java.util.Date` or `java.time.Instant` don't have comparable methods. It seems that in `java.time`, a `ZoneId` must always be provided to obtain "LocalFoo" or "OffsetBar".

From the javadoc of `java.sql.Date#toLocalDate()`:

> Converts this Date object to a LocalDate.
>   The conversion creates a
>   LocalDate that represents the same date value as this Date in local
>   time zone

Which timezone is "local time zone"? Does it depend on database or JVM settings?

Comment: It depends on JVM settings, for example on system property "user.timezone", too, see also [getting default zone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#systemDefault--)

Comment: Are you sure? It seems a bit odd with the other parts of java.time, that this default can not be overridden or made explicit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Timezones in SQL DATE vs java.sql.Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202857/timezones-in-sql-date-vs-java-sql-date)

Comment: That question looks very related, and I guess it means that it depends on system settings indeed. However `toLocalDate` is not mentioned there, and an explicit answer to that specific question would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

given a java.sql.Date-Object wrapping a fix millisecondsvalue, you will indeed get different LocalDate-Values depending on the Default-Timezone on your System.

I tried the following Code-Snippet:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(1465485798671l);
System.out.println(sqlDate.toLocalDate());
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tokyo"));
System.out.println(sqlDate.toLocalDate());
```

which yields:

   `2016-06-09
   2016-06-10`

Comment: Hang on, there's no `toLocalDate` in that code. What happens when we add it?

Comment: Hi Lars, sorry I forgot indeed to add .toLocalDate() - i've edited the code.

Comment: Excellent answer. Accepted!

Answer (score 5):

Conceptually, a `java.sql.Date` is the same as a `LocalDate`, ie. a date without time or time-zone. In practice, because `java.sql.Date` is implemented based on a `long` milliseconds, it has an implicit use of the system time-zone. So, the `toLocalDate()` method exists because the Java SQL spec leads want you to think of `java.sql.Date` as being without a time-zone.

Comment: Does that mean that `date.toLocalDate()` will return different LocalDate objects, depending on the system timezone of the current JVM?

Comment: So that's why the method has @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")? It's funny because java.util.Date deprecates most methods and java.sql.Date undeprecates some of them...