# Scala - java.sql.Date is parsed incorrectly when collecting distinct values from a DataSet

Tags: java, scala, date, apache-spark

I'm parsing dates from a Dataset[Transaction] objects in order to collect a set of dictinct values:

```
val distinctTransactionDates: Set[Date] = transactions.map(t => t.transaction_date).distinct().collect().toSet
```

But the dates are parsed incorrectly, for example if a transaction's Date is `2019-03-31`, the returned value is `2019-04-01`. When I logged to check `t.transaction_date.getTime` it is `1553990400000 (GMT: Sunday, 31 Mar 2019, 0:00:00)`. But the gap for some dates vs getTime is more than one day.

The Date here is a `java.sql.Date`

I can't figure out how to parse dates correctly in this case in order to get distinct values without any corrections. For the above example I'm expecting to get `2019-03-31`.

Comment: So 1553990400000 (which in GMT is 31 Mar 2019 00:00:00 alright) is becoming 2019-04-01? Weird. I think that [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help greatly.

Comment: From the looks of it, the issue may be due to the timezone. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9303340/9524896). This is speculation since I'd need to know a lot more

Comment: Time zone alone doesn’t seem to explain the unexpected result. Only in a time zone with offset between +24:00 and +47:59 would 1553990400000 fall on April 1. I believe that offsets go up to +14:00 in practice, while java.time supports offsets up to +18:00. Also @HarisNadeem

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to extract a date-only value from a date-with-time-of-day source, but failing to account for time zone.

Another problem: You are using the terrible `java.sql.Date` class that was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes. Specifically, `LocalDate`.

Your date-with-time-of-day source can be referred to as a moment, a specific point on the timeline. For any given moment the time-of-day and the date both vary by time zone around the globe. Noon in Paris is not noon in Montréal. And a new day dawns earlier in the east than in the west. You must get very clear on this to do proper date-time handling. One moment in nature can be viewed in many ways through human-created notions of time zones.

First extract your moment via JDBC as an `OffsetDateTime` object.

Code shown here is in Java syntax rather than Scala. Also, note that *java.time* uses immutable objects.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

Adjust into the time zone by which you want to perceive a date.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.withZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

Extract the date-only portion.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```