# Datetime in java

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a JDBC current **date and time** insert into Mysql Database.

It submits the current date and a fixed time into the Mysql date type field as `2012/05/25 00:00:00`.  The date part works very fine but the time doesn't shows any value.

I'm inserting the value with the following code:

```
java.util.Date myDate = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(myDate.getTime());
PreparedStatement PStmt = con.prepareStatement(Sql query);
PStmt.setDate(1,sqlDate);
```

Comment: Can you paste the code that inserts the date? What type of column did you use in the database?

Comment: java.util.Date myDate = new java.util.Date();<br/>               java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(myDate.getTime());<br/>                               PreparedStatement PStmt = con.prepareStatement(Sql query);<br/>            PStmt.setDate(1,sqlDate);

Comment: What is the type of column in MySQL?

Comment: @Narayan: Don't use java.sql.Date. Insert the java.util.Date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Use `java.util.Date` in your java class.

2) Set datatye `TIMESTAMP` in mysql.

```
Date CreatedDate= new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

For PreparedStatement: It may be like this:

```
PreparedStatement PStmt = con.prepareStatement(Sql query);
PStmt.setDate(1,CreatedDate);
```

Comment: What should be the prepared statement for this createdDate

Comment: It did not work for me because it loose the time. Use java.sql.Timestamp instead with setTimestamp(...)

Answer (score 20):

Use `java.sql.Timestamp` instead of `java.util.Date`

For example if you are using `PreparedStatement` to handle your insert, you can pass your date as;

```
java.util.Date date = new Date();
pst.setTimestamp(columIndex, new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime()));
```

Comment: +1: The problem is that `java.sql.Date` is *specifically* only a date, and so discards the time component.

Comment: It shows error when i tried to execute the insert statement ie, it shows error when i use pstmt.executeupdate() ;

Comment: You've not specified the error you're getting, I assume it is asking for the long as the parameter - see edited answer.

Comment: debug your time passed using `System.out.println(new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime()));` if this gives you the correct value, then assume the issue is the datatype held on the database table to hold `datetime`.

Comment: Should the last `.getTime()` be there in `new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime()).getTime()`?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, `PreparedStatement` doesn't have a method `setTimestamp(int, long)`, but it does have `setTimestamp(int, Timestamp)`, so shouldn't it be `pst.setTimestamp(columIndex, new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime()))`?

Comment: `pst.setTimestamp(columIndex, new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime()))` Is the correct assignment. I have corrected the typo. Ta!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to have timestamp as column type in mysql.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to note the distinction between `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date`

[java.util.Date vs java.sql.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305973/java-util-date-vs-java-sql-date)

**EDIT** also make sure you have the proper data type in the database (DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 1):

Although an old post, the answer is simple and depends on your requirement - as per your requirements use DATETIME data type and use the following

```
java.util.Date date = new Date();
pst.setTimestamp(columIndex, new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime()).getTime());
```

Let's see the reasoning from both the database and jdbc side.

Start from the data type in the database and pick appropriate one. The one which exactly suits your case is DATETIME as you want date and hour/min/sec. DATETIME type is used for storing wall clock time whereas TIMESTAMP is for a fixed point in time (some milliseconds after epoch). There is also difference in how both are stored internally in MySQL.

Now When you come to the JDBC side you have API methods for Date ( only date part), Timestamp (date and time) and Time (only time). That's all what the JDBC has to offer. So now, the API which suits your need is setTimestamp