# java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have a database table in oracle which has a column of type DATE. It looks like the table below

TABLE1

```
ID   PRODUCT_NAME  ITEM_CNT  ENTERED_DATE 
1         prod1      500       2012-07-01
2         prod2      1000      2012-06-30
```

in my java code, I want to get the total item_cnt for a certain date range. here is the code sample

```
String sql = "select sum(item_cnt) from table1 where entered_date between ? and ?";
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
ResultSet rset = null;

try{
   conn = getConnection(url, user, passwd);
   pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
   pstmt.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf(from_date)); //from_date is a string of "yyyy-mm-dd"
   pstmt.setDate(2, java.sql.Date.valueOf(to_date)); //to_date is a string of "yyyy-mm-dd"
   rset = pstmt.executeQuery();

   ....
}catch(SQLException e){
   //do something
} finally{
   //clean up
}
```

This code was running fine for a while until three days ago, I start getting the following exception at line pstmt.executeQuery();

```
    java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1157)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:290)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:884)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1167)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1289)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3628)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1493)
```

I tried to search for answers but couldn't find anything that really explains it. then I changed my sql query to

```
    "select sum(item_cnt) from table1 where entered_date between to_date(?, 'yyyy-mm-dd')  and to_date(?, 'yyyy-mm-dd')";
```

and instead of setting date, I changed the prepared statement to the following

```
     pstmt.setString(1, from_date);
     pstmt.setString(2, to_date);
```

Then the exception is gone.

Another confusion is, when I populate my table, I am still using the following

```
   pstmt.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf(date)); //date is a string of format "yyyy-mm-dd"
```

and it is still working. only the select statement was giving me exceptions.

Now everything is working but I really want to know why. Anyone knows?

I did upgrade my java to 1.7.0_03-b05 recently. and I am using ojdbc6.jar. The oracle is 11g. Could this be the driver's problem? is ojdbc7 out?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this exception while working over JDBC with IBM WAS 7.0, I had performed a JCA lifecycle management operation on data source. Which is like controlling the runtime status of the data source. **Purge** removes the contents of connection pool for the data source. However, in WAS this purging the pool will not affect the ongoing transactions. Check on your side.

Another thing which I performed was; the disk space was full on directory where Oracle was installed, I added extra space over that.

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice, I stay away from java.sql.Date class and use to_date() and to_char() functions while dealing with Dates in Java with Oracle.

Comment: could you explain why? because it's buggy? or bad performance? or something else?

Comment: [This stackoverflow discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305973/java-util-date-vs-java-sql-date) is very helpful.