# How to insert Date into MySQL Database table in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

How do I insert date, without time, to MySQL database table?
I tried these codes but I get the following exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Mar 05 00:00:00 GMT-08:00 2014,1,1)' at line 1
```

NOTE: In MySQL table, data type of this column I chose date datatype

```
String Date = "\\d\\d\\d\\d\\D[0-1][0-9]\\D[0-3][0-9]";
while (DateMatcher.find())  {   
    String date = DateMatcher.group().trim();

    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date myDate = formatter.parse(date);

    db.insert_date(myDate,2,1);           
}
```

I've problem only with date part
Query for inserting Date :

```
// insert DATE
public void insert_date(Date  date_str, int sentence_id ,int document_id ){
       // Statements allow to issue SQL queries to the database

    try {
        statement = connect.createStatement();

        System.out.println(  "insert into Date(date_Str,Sen_id,doc_id) " +
                 " values(" + date_str + "," +  sentence_id + "," + document_id +  ")"
                 );


        statement.executeUpdate(

         "insert into test.Date(date,Sen_id,doc_id)" +
         " values(" + date_str + "," +  sentence_id + "," + document_id + ")"
          );
    }
    catch(Exception e ){System.out.println(e);};
    // Result set get the result of the SQL query

}
```

Comment: Why not use the MySQL date datatype (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-types.html) and make configure the column as default?

Comment: It's visible where you went wrong, I just wonder why "programmers" don't read the error messages before asking questions. Pay attention to how you constructed MySQL query. Especially the quotes. Especially the one quote you didn't match.

Comment: Check your Query syntax.. something is wrong there.. post your query code

Comment: dear Micha Wiedenmann column type is date

Comment: dear N.B I read it & tried but i didn't get correct result

Comment: dear  Lakshmi I edited my code please tell me your note

Comment: **Avoid** using `Statement`. Rather, used `PreparedStatement` when storing `Objects` that aren't primitive.

Comment: Also try enclosing your date String 'date_str' in single quotes.

Comment: dear Raza now I can insert to MSQL table 'Thu Feb 02 00:00:00 GMT-08:00 2012' but how I can convert this type to 05-05-2012 some thing like that

Answer (score 11):

First of all, to persist a `java.util.Date` into a database in Java, you will have to convert it to [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html). The fortunate thing about JDBC SQL `Date` is that it's a subclass of Java `Date`.

Therefore, to create a [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) from `java.util.Date`, you will have to do this:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date myDate = formatter.parse(date);
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(myDate.getTime());

db.insert_date(sqlDate);
```

Make sure that `db.insert_date` accepts only [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html).

Where you will have to call your `PreparedStatement.setDate()` function.

See the related question [java.util.Date vs java.sql.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305973/java-util-date-vs-java-sql-date).

Comment: how i can convert this type of date ( Wed Mar 05 00:00:00 GMT-08:00 2014 ) cause while reading date it will converted to there type how I cab avoid this

Comment: insert into Date(date_Str,Sen_id,doc_id)  values(Wed Mar 05 00:00:00 GMT-08:00 2014,1,1)
while inserting date it will converted to above type

Comment: This is a different question all together. Just a hint, retrieve a `java.sql.Date` using `PreparedStatement.getDate()` and typecast it to `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score 0):

**NEVER** use `java.sql.Statement` for insert data. Use **ALWAYS** `java.sql.PrepartedStatement`. This because is a better way to avoid SQL Injection (see [this](http://bobby-tables.com/) for an explain). So, in your case, you can insert the date in this way:

```
statement = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test.Date(date, Sen_id, doc_id) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
statement.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(date_str.getTime());
statement.setInt(2, sentence_id);
statement.setInt(3, document_id);
```