# insert date to database in java

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Good day

I was trying to insert date into database and used the same solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645724/how-to-insert-date-into-mysql-database-table-in-java)

What I am facing now that after I used this solution, it show for me

```
Java.nullPointerException
```

Also I have tried `((JTextField) jDateChooser1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText()`
and it did not worked with me and says cannot convert date to string.

here is my codes :

```
      import java.util.Date;
    import java.sql.*;
     String Sql="insert into rect (recName,phoneNo,position,DOB,gender,Mstatus,nationality,quali,major,Uni,email,EngCom,AraCom,status,Stage,IntDate,source,interviewer,RecEval,comments,Attach) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) "; 
     try {

           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hr","root","");

          Date date = jDateChooser1.getDate();
       SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String strDate = formatter.getDateInstance().format(date);
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());

         Date datex = jDateChooser2.getDate();
         SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
         String intrDate = format.getDateInstance().format(datex);
         java.sql.Date sqlDatex = new java.sql.Date(datex.getTime());
            ps= con.prepareStatement(Sql);
            ps.setString(1, jTextField18.getText());
            ps.setString(2, jTextField1.getText());
            ps.setString(3, jTextField2.getText());

            ps.setDate(4,sqlDate);
             if(jRadioButton1.isSelected()== true){
             ps.setString(5, jRadioButton1.getText());
             } 
             else {
             ps.setString(5, jRadioButton2.getText());
             }
            ps.setString(6, (String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());
            ps.setString(7, jTextField3.getText());
            ps.setString(8, jTextField4.getText());
            ps.setString(9, jTextField5.getText());
            ps.setString(10, jTextField6.getText());
            ps.setString(11, jTextField8.getText());
            ps.setString(12, jTextField9.getText());
            ps.setString(13, jTextField10.getText());
            ps.setString(14, jTextField11.getText());
            ps.setString(15, jTextField12.getText());
           ps.setDate(16, sqlDatex);
            ps.setString(17, jTextField14.getText());
            ps.setString(18, jTextField15.getText());
            ps.setString(19, jTextArea1.getText());
            ps.setString(20, jTextArea2.getText());
            ps.setString(21, jTextField19.getText());
                       int i =ps.executeUpdate();
            if (i>0)
            {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data is Saved");
            }
            else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data is not Saved");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
```

Comment: `jDateChooser1.getDate().toString()` why?  Why not just use the `Date` value which is returned by `jDateChooser1.getDate()`?

Comment: At which line does it throw a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: When trying to insert date into database

Comment: Can you paste the output error?

Answer (score 1):

As @MadProgrammer said and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012751/get-jdatechooser-date-to-jlabel) post:

```
// Gives you the date
Date date = jDateChooser1.getDate();

// Transform to string
String strDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(date);
```