# Group by timestamp in jpql with JPA

Tags: java, jpa, sql-order-by, derby, jpql

guys!
I'm trying to group query results by timestamp in JPQL using JPA (EclipseLink + Derby) and use them for creating a Result object. 
My query is:

```
Select new com.restaurant.entities.Report(o.timeOfOrder, count(o.id), sum(o.price))";
    queryText+=" from Orders o ";
    queryText+="where o.timeOfOrder BETWEEN :start AND :end";
    queryText+=" group by o.timeOfOrder"
```

Unluckily, the only one millisec will make a huge difference, thus plain group by o.timeOfOrder doesn't work.

I have tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25512501/jpql-group-by-timestamp-as-a-date), however I've got

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Column reference 'ORDERS.TIMEOFORDER' is invalid, or is part of an invalid expression.  For a SELECT list with a GROUP BY, the columns and expressions being selected may only contain valid grouping expressions and valid aggregate expressions.
```

Perhaps, there are any another way out except changing the type of field in DB?

Comment: What time range you want to group? To day, hour, minute?

Comment: According to UserStory, analyst can choose the period for the research. Thereby, I suppose, it means that group by must include set of day, month and year filter simultaneously

Answer (score 2):

Your query would have to look something like this:

```
Select new com.restaurant.entities.Report(o.timeOfOrder, count(o.id), sum(o.price)) 
from Orders o 
where o.timeOfOrder BETWEEN :start AND :end 
group by year(o.timeOfOrder), month(o.timeOfOrder), day(o.timeOfOrder)
```

but the `year`, `month` and `day` functions are not jpql standard so you have to use FUNCTION to use your equivalent DB functions to perform what you want. Here's more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3676865/534877

Comment: Thanks for response! I have tried technik, mentioned by you, however, resultless due to an exception: both FUNC and FUNCTION forms of function invocation throw  java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Column reference 'ORDERS.TIMEOFORDER' is invalid, or is part of an invalid expression.  For a SELECT list with a GROUP BY, the columns and expressions being selected may only contain valid grouping expressions and valid aggregate expressions.           Weird situation baring in mind that my EclipseLink has 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b version :/

Answer (score 0):

The issue solves rather simply with a use of FUNCTION('period', fieldToTrim). 
However GROUPing BY result, you should bear in mind, that 'period' (not fieldToTrim) must (!) be in SELECT part, not only in GROUP BY.