# java.util.Date equals() doesn't seem to work as expected

Tags: java, date

### Problem

I have a `Map<Date, Foo>`, and a list of objects from the database with an `effectiveDate` property, and I want to check to see if the `Date` keys in my map are equal to any of the `effectiveDate`s in the database - if so, do stuff with `Foo`.

The code looks something like this:

```
for (Bar bar : databaseBars) {
  Foo foo = new Foo();
  if (dateMap.containsKey(bar.getEffectiveDate()) {
    foo = dateMap.get(bar.getEffectiveDate());
  }
  // do stuff with foo and bar
}
```

However, the `dateMap.containsKey` call always returns false, even though I'm sure it's sometimes there.

### Investigation

As a sanity check, I've printed out the long values of the dates, as well as the results of an `equals()` call and a `compareTo()` call:

```
for (Date keyDate : dateMap.keySet()) {
  if (keyDate == null) {
    continue; // make things simpler for now
  }

  Date effDate = bar.getEffectiveDate();

  String template = "keyDate: %d; effDate: %d; equals: %b; compareTo: %d\n";

  System.out.printf(template, keyDate.getTime(), effDate.getTime(), effDate.equals(keyDate), effDate.compareTo(keyDate));
}
```

The results:

```
keyDate: 1388534400000; effDate: 1388534400000; equals: false; compareTo: 0
keyDate: 1420070400000; effDate: 1388534400000; equals: false; compareTo: -1
keyDate: 1388534400000; effDate: 1420070400000; equals: false; compareTo: 1
keyDate: 1420070400000; effDate: 1420070400000; equals: false; compareTo: 0
keyDate: 1388534400000; effDate: 1388534400000; equals: false; compareTo: 0
keyDate: 1420070400000; effDate: 1388534400000; equals: false; compareTo: -1
keyDate: 1388534400000; effDate: 1420070400000; equals: false; compareTo: 1
keyDate: 1420070400000; effDate: 1420070400000; equals: false; compareTo: 0
keyDate: 1388534400000; effDate: 1388534400000; equals: false; compareTo: 0
keyDate: 1420070400000; effDate: 1388534400000; equals: false; compareTo: -1
keyDate: 1388534400000; effDate: 1420070400000; equals: false; compareTo: 1
keyDate: 1420070400000; effDate: 1420070400000; equals: false; compareTo: 0
```

### Question

1) Shouldn't `equals` and `compareTo` agree? (I assume the implementation of `java.util.Date` at least should try to follow the recommendation of `java.lang.Comparable`).

2) [The `Date#equals` doc says this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

> Thus, two Date objects are equal if and only if the getTime method returns the same long value for both.

...Looks like the `getTime` method returns the same long value for both of these dates, yet `equal` returns false. Any ideas why this might be happening? I've searched high and low, but I haven't found anyone describing the same problem.

P.S. I'm stuck using `java.util.Date`. Please don't just recommend JodaTime.

P.P.S. I realize I could just change the structure of this code and probably get it working. But this should work, and I don't want to just work around it, unless it's a known issue or something. It just seems *wrong*.

Comment: What `Date` implementation does your database return?

Comment: Ooh, interesting:
keyDate.getClass() = class java.util.Date, but effDate.getClass() = class java.sql.Timestamp.

Comment: Ah, well, there you go. A `Timestamp` is a `Date`, but a `Date` is not a `Timestamp` (it has its own implementation it seems).

Comment: Wow, that's janky: [The Timestamp.equals(Object) method never returns true when passed an object that isn't an instance of java.sql.Timestamp, because the nanos component of a date is unknown. As a result, the Timestamp.equals(Object) method is not symmetric with respect to the java.util.Date.equals(Object) method.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As [Mureinik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2422776/mureinik) hinted at and [Sotirios Delimanolis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis) pointed out more specifically, the problem here is with the implementation of `java.util.Date`.

`java.util.Date` is extended by 3 classes in the `java.sql` package, all of which seem to do similar things and whose distinction in java is not at all clear (seems like the reason for their existence is simply to make java classes which align more accurately to SQL datatypes) - for more information on their differences, check out [this very detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2306051/2347824).

Now, in what seems like a serious design flaw, someone decided to make [`equals()` asymmetric with `java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) - that is, `timestamp.equals(date)` could return false even if `date.equals(timestamp)` returns true. Great idea.

I wrote a few lines to see which `java.sql` classes demonstrate this ridiculous property - apparently it's just `Timestamp`. This code:

```
java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();

java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());

System.out.println("sqlDate equals utilDate:\t" + sqlDate.equals(utilDate));
System.out.println("utilDate equals sqlDate:\t" + utilDate.equals(sqlDate));

java.sql.Time time = new java.sql.Time(utilDate.getTime());

System.out.println("time equals utilDate:\t\t" + time.equals(utilDate));
System.out.println("utilDate equals time:\t\t" + utilDate.equals(time));

java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(utilDate.getTime());

System.out.println("timestamp equals utilDate:\t" + timestamp.equals(utilDate));
System.out.println("utilDate equals timestamp:\t" + utilDate.equals(timestamp));
```

Yields this:

```
sqlDate equals utilDate:    true
utilDate equals sqlDate:    true
time equals utilDate:       true
utilDate equals time:       true
timestamp equals utilDate:  false
utilDate equals timestamp:  true
```

Since [`java.util.HashMap` uses `parameter.equals(key)` in it's implementation of `containsKey()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29) (rather than `key.equals(parameter)`), this one strange result shows up in the given situation.

So, how to get around this?

1) Use a `Long` key in the map rather than a `Date` (as Mureinik noted) - since `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Timestamp` return the same value from `getTime()`, it shouldn't matter which implementation you're using, the key will be the same. This way does seem like the simplest.

2) Standardize the date object before using it in the map. This way requires a tiny bit more work, but to me seems more desirable as it's more clear what the map is - a bunch of `Foo` each stored against a moment in time. This is the way I ended up using, with the following method:

```
public Date getStandardizedDate(Date date) {
  return new Date(date.getTime());
}
```

It takes an extra method call (and kind of a ridiculous one at that), but to me the increased readability of the code involving the `Map<Date, Foo>` is worth it.

Answer (score 3):

Part 1: "Shouldn't `equals` agree with `compareTo`?*

No; compareTo should agree with equals, but the reverse is irrelevant.

compareTo is about sorting order. equals is about equality. Consider race cars, that may be sorted by fastest lap time in practice to determine starting position. Equal lap times does not mean they are the same car.

Part 2: Equal dates.

Database calls will return a java.sql.Date, which although it is assignable to java.util.Dare, because it extends that, will not be equal, because the class is different.

A work around may be:

```
java.util.Date test;
java.sql.Date date;
if (date.equals(new java.sql.Date(test.getTime()))
```

Comment: To this I would suggest to take a look at Effective Java, by Joshua Bloch, where he discusses `equals()` and `compareTo()` in great detail.  He mentions the following:

Comment: @torngat What _does_ Joshua mention? :)

Answer (score 2):

A `Date` object returned from a database would probably be a `java.sql.Timestamp`, which cannot be equal to a `java.util.Date` object. I'd just take the long returned from `getTime()`, and use that as a key in your `HashMap`.

Comment: I thought so too, but it seems to work fine on Java 8. `java.util.Date` checks `instanceof Date`, which `java.sql.Date` is.