# Setting timestamp to Calendar in java

Tags: java

I am using following code to set SQL `timestamp` in calendar instance, it is working fine. Is this correct?

```
 TimeStamp expireDate= ab.getUExpireDate();
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
 cal.setTime(expireDate); // ← this line
```

Comment: Timestamp is a subclass of java.util.Date, so it will accept timestamps too

Answer (score 1):

You can check the difference in util.Date and sql.Date in the following post

[java.util.Date vs java.sql.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305973/java-util-date-vs-java-sql-date)

Answer (score 0):

You can import:

1)java.sql.Timestamp

***The biggest difference between java.sql.Date and java.sql.Timestamp is that the java.sql.Date only keeps the date, not the time, of the date it represents. So, for instance, if you create a java.sql.Date using the date and time 2014-12-24 21:20, then the time (21:20) would be cut off. If you use a java.sql.Timestamp then the time is kept.

method to add timeStamp object in Calender is :

2) cal.setTime(expireDate);

Comment: 2. can 't use Cal.set(expireDate), do you mean cal.setTime(expireDate)