# JDBC SQL prepared statement calling function but getting expression error

Tags: java, sql, date, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm trying to insert a TIMESTAMP into a table, but the timestamp inserted will always be X days away from now. Here is my code:

```
ps = c.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tablename (uuid, pool, expires) VALUES (?, ?, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL ? DAY)");
ps.setString(1, player.getUniqueId().toString());
ps.setInt(2, plugin.s.DEFAULT_POOL);
ps.setInt(3, plugin.s.PAYMENT_DAYS);
```

But when this executes a syntax error occurs. If there is a better method for doing this, or a fix for this, I'd like to know. Thanks!

Comment: please post the actual error you are getting

Comment: what exactly is the syntax error, and what DB is this for? I'm guessing mysql...

Comment: You will have to replace **DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL ? DAY)** with java code.

Comment: please post all the relevant code, the stack trace and the table structure.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all note that your query is missing a closing `)` at the end, the following:

```
VALUES (?, ?, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL ? DAY)
```

Should be:

```
VALUES (?, ?, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL ? DAY))
```

Then may be you need to use a `new Date()` and add to it the `PAYMENT_DAYS` for the date type, try the following:

```
public static Date addDaysToCurrentDate(int days) {
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
     Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
     c.setTime(new Date()); 
     c.add(Calendar.DATE, days); 
     return sdf.parse(c.getTime());
}

ps = c.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tablename (uuid, pool, expires) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
ps.setString(1, player.getUniqueId().toString());
ps.setInt(2, plugin.s.DEFAULT_POOL);
ps.setInt(3, addDaysToCurrentDate(plugin.s.PAYMENT_DAYS));
```

Comment: That PAYMENT_DAYS is an integer number of days, not a date object.

Comment: Ah Ok I see, in that case we just need to convert it to date, I am Editing my answer.

Comment: I would just wait for the OP to fix the parenthesis. I'm not sure the problem goes beyond that.

Comment: Yes I think, the missing parentheses may be the cause of the problem.

Comment: So I added the parenthesis, and the syntax error went away. However, the entry still shows the timestamp the entry was made, not X days in the future, like I wanted.

Comment: Now the weirdest part so far is that that exact command, put in a raw sql script, with the prepare and execute statements, worked perfectly for me. I just need to figure out what's wrong with my JDBC code...

Answer (score 0):

try using select instead of values

```
insert into ... select ?,?, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL ? DAY))
```

or replace with java code as suggested:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(new Date()); 
c.add(Calendar.DATE, days); 
ps.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(c.getTime().getTime()));
```

Comment: Does java.sql.Date have both time and date parts? I want to have both.

Comment: @Pocketkid2 See: [java.util.Date vs java.sql.Date](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2305973/642706)

Answer (score 0):

```
ps = c.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tablename (uuid, pool, expires) VALUES (?, ?, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL ? DAY)");
```

`? DAY`, this question mark needs to be an integer.
You need to calculate.