# Can we use java.util.Date for sql or oracle operations?

Tags: java

In java we have two Date classes like java.util.Date and java.sql.Date.So here can i use java.util.Date for sql operations.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.util.Date vs java.sql.Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305973/java-util-date-vs-java-sql-date)

Answer (score 1):

You can actually populate a java.sql.Date with the time value of a java.util.Date :

```
java.util.Date d1 = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Date d2 = new java.sql.Date(d1.getTime());
```