# JDBC date to SQL date

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, jdbc

I have been using Java to store some records from a csv file.
One of these records is a date. The problem here is I am using JDBC to store these records in a database. Now, the Date object of Java is showing an error while putting it into the database. I have been stuck on this for a while. Please let me know how to solve this. I have used type Date in mysql for storing it into the database. Here is the part creating the problem.

```
DateFormat d1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date d = new Date(); 
System.out.println(d1.format(d));
String sql = "INSERT INTO TESTING"+
            "VALUES("+"DATE_FORMAT("+d+","+"'%Y-%m-%d'"+"))";
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

If I execute this directly in MySqlWorkBench, it is storing the date properly. But through JDBC it is a problem.

***The error is as shown below :***

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Jun 30 14:04:03 IST 2016,'%Y-%m-%d'))' at line 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3277)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:1402)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:1317)
    at payex.writeDB(payex.java:221)
    at payextestdrive.main(payextestdrive.java:11)
```

Comment: "Now, the Date object of Java is showing an error while putting it into the database" - What error? Using string concatenation is *not* right solution here... you should absolutely be using a PreparedStatement, but you need to use `java.sql.Date`, not `java.util.Date`.

Comment: You can refer to this post too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305973/java-util-date-vs-java-sql-date

Comment: `"INSERT INTO TESTING"+"VALUES...` can't work

Comment: You should really be using PreparedStatement and queries with parameter plaeholders instead of concatenating values into a query string.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear

```
right syntax to use near 'Jun 30 14:04:03 IST 2016,'%Y-%m-%d'))'
```

The format you provided is MMM DD HH:mm:ss Z YYYY, but the system expects %Y-%m-%d

Try

```
DateFormat d1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date d = new Date(); 
System.out.println(d1.format(d));
String sql = "INSERT INTO TESTING"+
            " VALUES("+"DATE_FORMAT('"+d1.format(d)+"',"+"'%Y-%m-%d'"+"))";
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

or simply

```
DateFormat d1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date d = new Date(); 
System.out.println(d1.format(d));
String sql = "INSERT INTO TESTING"+
            " VALUES('"+d1.format(d)+"')";
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I tried this but I'm getting an exception.

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '2008'
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2983)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3277)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:1402)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:1317)
 at payex.writeDB(payex.java:221)
 at payextestdrive.main(payextestdrive.java:11)

Answer (score 1):

You add `d.toString()` to the SQL command when you want to add the formatted date string. Also a space is missing between the table name and `VALUES`:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO TESTING VALUES(DATE_FORMAT(" + d1.format(d) +",'%Y-%m-%d'))";
```

Comment: Hey I tried this. Thanks for your answer. But there's an exception again.

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '2008'
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2983)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3277)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:1402)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:1317)
 at payex.writeDB(payex.java:220)
 at payextestdrive.main(payextestdrive.java:11)