# incompatible types: java.util.Date cannot be converted to java.sql.Date jdbc preparedstatement

Tags: java, date, jdbc

I have a code on sql prepared statement and I am trying to convert util.date format to sql.date format but not head way

```
//this is a handle of prepatedstatement
ps.setDate(6, rec.getDate());
```

I am converting the date from a string to a date class in a DAO class as shown

```
String s = hr_recdate.getText();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            java.util.Date date = sdf.parse(s);
rec.setDate(date);
```

Please how do I convert rec.getDate() of java.util to sql.util

Comment: @Jens Yes that answered my question. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24789834/6691596