# Hibernate + Mysql : Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

All,

I am using Spring, Hibernate and MySQL to persist some records to a queue which I process later.

Since I am using Java 8, the recommendation is to use JodaTime library rather than Java SQL Date c.f. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305973/java-util-date-vs-java-sql-date)

**Model**

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "order_job_queue")
public class CancelReward implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "processed_state")
    private String processedState;

    @Column(name = "order_reference_id")
    private int orderReferenceId;

    @Column(name = "creation_date", columnDefinition = "DATETIME DEFAULT")
    private DateTime creationDate;

    @Column(name = "last_checked_date", columnDefinition = "DATETIME DEFAULT")
    private DateTime lastCheckedDate; ...

@PrePersist
protected void onCreate() {
    creationDate = new DateTime().toDateTime();
}

@PreUpdate
protected void onUpdate() {
    lastCheckedDate = new DateTime().toDateTime();
}
```

**Table**

```
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`processed_state` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`order_reference_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`creation_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`last_checked_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
```

**Dependency Versions**

- Spring Framework - 4.3.3
- Hibernate - 4.3.5
- Hibernate JPA2 API - 1
- MySQL Connector - 5.1.40

When I try to save an entity I get this stack trace complaining about truncation.

> Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '��' for column 'creation_date' at row 1
>   Error while processing request: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement

I've tried using Java SQL Date as well, not sure how to fix this one.a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the standard date in java:

```
import java.util.Date;
```

`java.sql.Timestamp` should also work but I never tried it myself.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. It is dissapointing that JodaTime does not work considering it implements Date.util interface :(