# JAVA Get Milliseconds since Epoch from ISO_DATE_TIME

Tags: java, date, time, flink-streaming, java-time

I'm trying to get Milliseconds since Epoch from ISO_DATE_TIME and i have been reading so many article.

My starting point is this: **2020-10-06T11:51:45.964+01:00**

My ending point is a **long** that consider milliseconds. (https://currentmillis.com/)

I'm using a message coming from Kafka into Flink, and the time stamp is in the payload of the message.

This is my code:

```
public void setKafkaTime(String kafkaTime) {
    DateTimeFormatter sdr = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXX");
    LocalDateTime MydateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(kafkaTime,sdr);
    NOT WORKING -> Date date = Date.from(MydateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));
    Long tn = date.getTime();
    this.time = tn;
}
```

There is so much about the topic and i tried many ways, starting from the Java doc:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME
But mine is not ISO-8601 standard as i have second and milliseconds.

i have been using some important tips from previous questions like this one, where i found the pattern
[Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion/)
and i got this nice table.
[image]

To use .getTime() I need a *java.util.Date* to convert *LocalDateTime* to *Date* I got in trouble with an error asking me for a *Java.sql.Date.*

[image]

I have been reading about the difference between the two, and from what I understood Java.sql doesn't consider the time, so I denfinetly should not use it.

[java.util.Date vs java.sql.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305973/java-util-date-vs-java-sql-date)

I'm confident about the top two lines of the code, for the rest I'm struggling. I really can't get how to obtain a long. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Don’t use `Date`, it’s poorly designed, long outdated and a detour. Don’t use `LocalDateTime` as it cannot define a point in time and hence no milliseconds count from the epoch. You also don’t need to use any formatter. `OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-10-06T11:51:45.964+01:00").toInstant().toEpochMilli()` yields 1601981505964.

Comment: And yes, indeed your format is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). Seconds and fraction of second are optional in that format.

Comment: Many thanks, one line and it is all done!

Comment: SimAzz - Do not stop here...whenever you get some time, go read answers by @OleV.V. and you will learn about date-time much faster than you can do from a tutorial or a textbook.

Comment: @Arvind Kumar Avinash - I will! thanks for the suggestion! s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.  I used a zoned time and then converted that to an instant to get the milliseconds.

```
public  void setKafkaTime(String kafkaTime) {
    DateTimeFormatter sdr = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSzzz");
    ZonedDateTime MydateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(kafkaTime,sdr);
    this.time = MydateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!