# Java: Difference between two dates in Months

Tags: java, date

How can I find the difference between two Dates in units of whole months, in Java?

Comment: The easiest way is to learn JODA.

Comment: @anon If you edit to define exactly what you mean by "whole months", this Question could be re-opened and might prove quite useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using JodaTime a lot of date/time functionality is a lot easier to implement:

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

there were plans to incorporate the library into Java 7, though this unfortunately did not happen:

[Joda Time to be included in Java 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724474/joda-time-to-be-included-in-java-7)

Comment: Most likely the new date and time API is going to be included in Java 8 - see [Project ThreeTen](http://threeten.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend looking at [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) since it's a better, more-intuitive and thread-safe API. Check out [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460701/how-to-calculate-difference-only-in-months-using-javas-joda-api) for a Joda-specific answer to your question.

Note that the Joda API was the foundation for the new Java Date API (JSR-310) and is scheduled for release in Java 8 (it got dropped from Java 7). It's a de facto standard and learning that API will be valuable.