# Is there any field converter for java.util.Date?

Tags: java, playorm

I would like to use a Date field in my playOrm mapping. However, if I use

```
private Date birthDate;
```

in my bean, it gives me an exception saying this type is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can add Date if you open an issue.  I was thinking of actually throwing an exception when people use Date that says this though instead..

> Please use LocalDate, LocalTime or LocalDateTime from joda-time which
>   was supposed to be added in jdk7 but more than likely will end up in
>   jdk8.  The reason for this is java.util.Date and Calendar from java
>   are buggy and have lots of known bugs in the jdk bug system.

See this as well
[Joda Time to be included in Java 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724474/joda-time-to-be-included-in-java-7)

If however, you still want to use Date, here is how

```
Map<Class, Converter> converters = new HashMap<Class, Converter>();
Converter d = new DateConverter();
converters.put(Date.class, d);
```

Then you need to implement the Converter interface with your DateConverter class and implement the byte[] to Date and Date to byte[] and String to Date and Date to String methods.  NOTE: These methods are all called for S-SQL and for converting entities...it all uses the same converters.

The string conversions are VERY important as the command line tool will use them to convert your command line S-SQL to query the objects.

HOWEVER, if you want it built-in to PlayOrm, just open an issue and I can do it pretty quickly BUT I still suggest you use LocalDateTime instead in joda-time as it is more reliable and you can do more with it....after using joda-time quite a bit, it is on-par with C# date apis and way better than the old java stuff.

Dean

Comment: Sorry, when you said issue I was guessing it was a stackoverflow question :D I guess you meant at github.

Comment: yup, add an issue on github ;)....sorry, I should have been more clear on that one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking for, but as stated in the Java API for Date, "As of JDK 1.1, the `Calendar` class should be used to convert between dates and time fields and the `DateFormat` class should be used to format and parse date strings. The corresponding methods in Date are deprecated."

Comment: and the future versions are supposed to pick up joda-time classes as Calendar had just as many bugs as Date did....reference... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724474/joda-time-to-be-included-in-java-7